# Parsing domain from a URL

Tags: php

I need to build a function which parses the domain from a URL.

So, with

```
http://google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html
```

or

```
http://www.google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html
```

it should return `google.com`

with

```
http://google.co.uk/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html
```

it should return `google.co.uk`.

Comment: see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288810/get-the-subdomain-from-a-url/14688913#14688913

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is a bit more than just "looking in the manual". PHP's `parse_url()` returns the _host_, not the _domain_.

Comment: @w3dk: It would still have been a fantastic starting point, allowing this question to be about that limitation of `parse_url` rather than a vague "what can I do".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit your defense is disingenuous given your reputation - more simply you can admit that you did not read the question completely

Comment: https://gist.github.com/praisedpk/64bdb80d28144aa78d58469324432277

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then what is the answer? Still looking for a way to get the -domain- not the -host-.

Comment: @AutumnLeonard: The domain _is_ the host.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not necessarily. https://support.suso.com/supki/What_is_the_difference_between_a_hostname_and_a_domain_name

Answer (score 389, accepted):

Check out [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url):

```
$url = 'http://google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html';
$parse = parse_url($url);
echo $parse['host']; // prints 'google.com'
```

`parse_url` doesn't handle really badly mangled urls very well, but is fine if you generally expect decent urls.

Comment: One thing parse_url() does not do is only return the domain.  If you add www.google.com or www.google.co.uk, it will return the host as well.  Any suggestions for that?

Comment: @Crad, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272805/how-to-handle-mozillas-top-domain-name-list-with-php

Comment: `parse_url` do not handle subdomains, but Purl does: https://github.com/jwage/purl

Comment: [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) would possibly parse URLs with a domain that contains dashes wrongly. Could not find definite proof, but check out [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51192). `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` uses `parse_url()` internally.

Comment: Or simply: `print parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST))` if you don't need the `$parse` array for anything else.

Comment: Does not handle `domain.eu` which is perfectly valid domain.

Comment: @tftd - That's because `parse_url` expects to be passed a [**url**](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/URL), but `domain.eu` is only the domain-name/hostname portion of the url.  "`parse_url` parses a URL and returns an associative array containing any of the various components of the URL that are present. This function is **not meant to validate** the given URL..."

Comment: Single line: `parse_url('https://google.com/cheezburger')['host'];`

Answer (score 114):

```
$domain = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
```

**This would return the `google.com` for both http://google.com/... and http://www.google.com/...**

Comment: 'cause it will still return the server if you put in "server.google.com" or "www3.google.com"...

Comment: Not all subdomains are www, crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com, myblog.blogspot.com are a few examples.

Answer (score 25):

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#93983

> for some odd reason, parse_url
> returns the host (ex. example.com) as
> the path when no scheme is provided in
> the input url. So I've written a quick
> function to get the real host:

```
function getHost($Address) { 
   $parseUrl = parse_url(trim($Address)); 
   return trim($parseUrl['host'] ? $parseUrl['host'] : array_shift(explode('/', $parseUrl['path'], 2))); 
} 

getHost("example.com"); // Gives example.com 
getHost("http://example.com"); // Gives example.com 
getHost("www.example.com"); // Gives www.example.com 
getHost("http://example.com/xyz"); // Gives example.com
```

Comment: Don’t forget to quote your strings like `host` and `path`.

Comment: If I use example.com, php displays a notice: `Message: Undefined index: host` any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately the subdomain is still included with this approach, see your example #3.

Comment: @Zim3r Change the first part of the ternary to `!empty($parseUrl['host'])`.

Comment: LOL if it doesn't have a scheme, it's not a URL.

Comment: The question mentiones that www. should be removed too so this answer is incorrect

Answer (score 17):

```
function get_domain($url = SITE_URL)
{
    preg_match("/[a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6}$/", parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST), $_domain_tld);
    return $_domain_tld[0];
}

get_domain('http://www.cdl.gr'); //cdl.gr
get_domain('http://cdl.gr'); //cdl.gr
get_domain('http://www2.cdl.gr'); //cdl.gr
```

Comment: No working for me either: 

example.com // Incorrect: empty string
http://example.com // Correct: example.com
www.example.com // Incorrect: empty string
http://example.com/xyz // Correct: example.com

Comment: This is a great answer and deserves more credit. Just add this line as the first line in the function and it also solves the problems of MangeshSathe and jenlampton:
if((substr($url,0,strlen('http://')) <> 'http://') && (substr($url,0,strlen('https://')) <> 'https://')) $url = 'http://'.$url;

Answer (score 15):

The code that was meant to work 100% didn't seem to cut it for me, I did patch the example a little but found code that wasn't helping and problems with it. so I changed it out to a couple of functions (to save asking for the list from Mozilla all the time, and removing the cache system). This has been tested against a set of 1000 URLs and seemed to work.

```
function domain($url)
{
    global $subtlds;
    $slds = "";
    $url = strtolower($url);

    $host = parse_url('http://'.$url,PHP_URL_HOST);

    preg_match("/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/", $host, $matches);
    foreach($subtlds as $sub){
        if (preg_match('/\.'.preg_quote($sub).'$/', $host, $xyz)){
            preg_match("/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/", $host, $matches);
        }
    }

    return @$matches[0];
}

function get_tlds() {
    $address = 'http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1';
    $content = file($address);
    foreach ($content as $num => $line) {
        $line = trim($line);
        if($line == '') continue;
        if(@substr($line[0], 0, 2) == '/') continue;
        $line = @preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]/", '', $line);
        if($line == '') continue;  //$line = '.'.$line;
        if(@$line[0] == '.') $line = substr($line, 1);
        if(!strstr($line, '.')) continue;
        $subtlds[] = $line;
        //echo "{$num}: '{$line}'"; echo "<br>";
    }

    $subtlds = array_merge(array(
            'co.uk', 'me.uk', 'net.uk', 'org.uk', 'sch.uk', 'ac.uk', 
            'gov.uk', 'nhs.uk', 'police.uk', 'mod.uk', 'asn.au', 'com.au',
            'net.au', 'id.au', 'org.au', 'edu.au', 'gov.au', 'csiro.au'
        ), $subtlds);

    $subtlds = array_unique($subtlds);

    return $subtlds;    
}
```

Then use it like

```
$subtlds = get_tlds();
echo domain('www.example.com') //outputs: example.com
echo domain('www.example.uk.com') //outputs: example.uk.com
echo domain('www.example.fr') //outputs: example.fr
```

I know I should have turned this into a class, but didn't have time.

Comment: https://github.com/leth/registered-domains-php this pretty much does what you did

Answer (score 11):

Please consider replacring the accepted solution with the following:

parse_url() will always include any sub-domain(s), so this function doesn't parse domain names very well.
Here are some examples:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html';
$parse = parse_url($url);
echo $parse['host']; // prints 'www.google.com'

echo parse_url('https://subdomain.example.com/foo/bar', PHP_URL_HOST);
// Output: subdomain.example.com

echo parse_url('https://subdomain.example.co.uk/foo/bar', PHP_URL_HOST);
// Output: subdomain.example.co.uk
```

Instead, you may consider this pragmatic solution.
It will cover many, but not all domain names -- for instance, lower-level domains such as 'sos.state.oh.us' are not covered.

```
function getDomain($url) {
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

    if(filter_var($host,FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        // IP address returned as domain
        return $host; //* or replace with null if you don't want an IP back
    }

    $domain_array = explode(".", str_replace('www.', '', $host));
    $count = count($domain_array);
    if( $count>=3 && strlen($domain_array[$count-2])==2 ) {
        // SLD (example.co.uk)
        return implode('.', array_splice($domain_array, $count-3,3));
    } else if( $count>=2 ) {
        // TLD (example.com)
        return implode('.', array_splice($domain_array, $count-2,2));
    }
}

// Your domains
    echo getDomain('http://google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html'); // google.com
    echo getDomain('http://www.google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html'); // google.com
    echo getDomain('http://google.co.uk/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html'); // google.co.uk

// TLD
    echo getDomain('https://shop.example.com'); // example.com
    echo getDomain('https://foo.bar.example.com'); // example.com
    echo getDomain('https://www.example.com'); // example.com
    echo getDomain('https://example.com'); // example.com

// SLD
    echo getDomain('https://more.news.bbc.co.uk'); // bbc.co.uk
    echo getDomain('https://www.bbc.co.uk'); // bbc.co.uk
    echo getDomain('https://bbc.co.uk'); // bbc.co.uk

// IP
    echo getDomain('https://1.2.3.45');  // 1.2.3.45
```

Finally, Jeremy Kendall's [PHP Domain Parser](https://github.com/jeremykendall/php-domain-parser) allows you to parse the domain name from a url. [League URI Hostname Parser](https://uri.thephpleague.com/domain-parser/1.0/) will also do the job.

Comment: Hi, this is good but it doesn't work with IP addresses. Still, great work.

Answer (score 6):

If you want extract host from string `http://google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html`, usage of parse_url() is acceptable solution for you.

But if you want extract domain or its parts, you need package that using [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/). Yes, you can use string functions arround parse_url(), but it will produce incorrect results sometimes.

I recomend [TLDExtract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract) for domain parsing, here is sample code that show diff:

```
$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();

# For 'http://google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html'

$url = 'http://google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html';

parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST); // will return google.com

$result = $extract->parse($url);
$result->getFullHost(); // will return 'google.com'
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return 'google.com'
$result->getSuffix(); // will return 'com'

# For 'http://search.google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html'

$url = 'http://search.google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html';

parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST); // will return 'search.google.com'

$result = $extract->parse($url);
$result->getFullHost(); // will return 'search.google.com'
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return 'google.com'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion. I hate adding another library for what _appears_ to be a simple task, but then I saw this quote on their readme applied to me: "Everybody gets this wrong. Splitting on the '.' and taking the last 2 elements goes a long way only if you're thinking of simple e.g. .com domains. Think parsing http://forums.bbc.co.uk for example: the naive splitting method above will give you 'co' as the domain and 'uk' as the TLD, instead of 'bbc' and 'co.uk' respectively."

Comment: The result for splitting dots while not what we want to happen on our beloved .co.uk domains, actually is the correct result, the co being a second level with uk being the top level. Webmaster often do not realise that.

Answer (score 6):

I've found that @philfreo's solution (referenced from php.net) is pretty well to get fine result but in some cases it shows php's "notice" and "Strict Standards" message. Here a fixed version of this code.

```
function getHost($url) { 
   $parseUrl = parse_url(trim($url)); 
   if(isset($parseUrl['host']))
   {
       $host = $parseUrl['host'];
   }
   else
   {
        $path = explode('/', $parseUrl['path']);
        $host = $path[0];
   }
   return trim($host); 
} 
  
echo getHost("http://example.com/anything.html");           // example.com
echo getHost("http://www.example.net/directory/post.php");  // www.example.net
echo getHost("https://example.co.uk");                      // example.co.uk
echo getHost("www.example.net");                            // example.net
echo getHost("subdomain.example.net/anything");             // subdomain.example.net
echo getHost("example.net");                                // example.net
```

###### I have provided an updated code to answer the question more accurately because of the questioner also wanted to remove the 'www' part from the given 'url'

[The solution below has been updated on July 29, 2023]

```
function getHost($url, $accept_www=false){ 
    $URIs = parse_url(trim($url)); 
    $host = !empty($URIs['host'])? $URIs['host'] : explode('/', $URIs['path'])[0];
    return $accept_www == false? str_ireplace('www.', '', $host) : $host;  
}
```

###### Use examples:

```
echo getHost("http://example.com/anything.html", 1).'<br>';           // example.com
echo getHost("http://www.example.net/directory/post.php", 1).'<br>';  // www.example.net
echo getHost("https://example.co.uk", 1).'<br>';                      // example.co.uk
echo getHost("www.example.net", 1).'<br>';                            // example.net
echo getHost("subdomain.example.net/anything", 1).'<br>';             // subdomain.example.net
echo getHost("http://blog.example.net/anything").'<br>';              // blog.example.net
echo getHost("example.net", 1).'<br>';                                // example.net

echo '<br> ===== without "www" ===== <br><br>';

echo getHost("http://example.com/anything.html").'<br>';             // example.com
echo getHost("http://www.example.net/directory/post.php").'<br>';    // example.net
echo getHost("https://example.co.uk").'<br>';                        // example.co.uk
echo getHost("www.example.net").'<br>';                              // example.net
echo getHost("subdomain.example.net/anything").'<br>';               // subdomain.example.net
echo getHost("http://blog.example.net/anything").'<br>';             // blog.example.net
echo getHost("example.net").'<br>';                                  // example.net
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pass PHP_URL_HOST into parse_url function as second parameter

```
$url = 'http://google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html';
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
print $host; // prints 'google.com'
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the answer above, however, the question is requiring the _domain_, which isn't necessarily the same as the _host_.

Comment: see comment above about scheme: for some odd reason, parse_url returns the host (ex. example.com) as the path when no scheme is provided in the input url. So I've written a quick function to get the real host:

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code i made that 100% finds only the domain name, since it takes mozilla sub tlds to account. Only thing you have to check is how you make cache of that file, so you dont query mozilla every time.

For some strange reason, domains like co.uk are not in the list, so you have to make some hacking and add them manually. Its not cleanest solution but i hope it helps someone.

```
//=====================================================
static function domain($url)
{
    $slds = "";
    $url = strtolower($url);

            $address = 'http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1';
    if(!$subtlds = @kohana::cache('subtlds', null, 60)) 
    {
        $content = file($address);
        foreach($content as $num => $line)
        {
            $line = trim($line);
            if($line == '') continue;
            if(@substr($line[0], 0, 2) == '/') continue;
            $line = @preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]/", '', $line);
            if($line == '') continue;  //$line = '.'.$line;
            if(@$line[0] == '.') $line = substr($line, 1);
            if(!strstr($line, '.')) continue;
            $subtlds[] = $line;
            //echo "{$num}: '{$line}'"; echo "<br>";
        }
        $subtlds = array_merge(Array(
            'co.uk', 'me.uk', 'net.uk', 'org.uk', 'sch.uk', 'ac.uk', 
            'gov.uk', 'nhs.uk', 'police.uk', 'mod.uk', 'asn.au', 'com.au',
            'net.au', 'id.au', 'org.au', 'edu.au', 'gov.au', 'csiro.au',
            ),$subtlds);

        $subtlds = array_unique($subtlds);
        //echo var_dump($subtlds);
        @kohana::cache('subtlds', $subtlds);
    }


    preg_match('/^(http:[\/]{2,})?([^\/]+)/i', $url, $matches);
    //preg_match("/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|)[a-zA-Z-]([^\/]+)/i", $url, $matches);
    $host = @$matches[2];
    //echo var_dump($matches);

    preg_match("/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/", $host, $matches);
    foreach($subtlds as $sub) 
    {
        if (preg_match("/{$sub}$/", $host, $xyz))
        preg_match("/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/", $host, $matches);
    }

    return @$matches[0];
}
```

Comment: The reason the domain `co.uk` was not on the list, was because it was a list of  TLD's, not of domains. The ccTLD has changed a lot since this answer was written. Notably: "New registrations directly under .uk have been accepted by Nominet since 10 June 2014 08:00 BST, however there is a reservation period for existing customers who already have a .co.uk, .org.uk, .me.uk, .net.uk, .ltd.uk or .plc.uk domain to claim the corresponding .uk domain, which runs until 07:59 BST on ***10 June 2019***." (**[Source](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/.uk)**)

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding this answer late since this is the answer that pops up most on Google...

You can use PHP to...

```
$url = "www.google.co.uk";
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
// $host == "www.google.co.uk"
```

to grab the *host* but not the *private domain* to which the host refers. (Example `www.google.co.uk` is the host, but `google.co.uk` is the private domain)

To grab the private domain, you must need know the list of public suffixes to which one *can* register a private domain. This list happens to be curated by Mozilla at https://publicsuffix.org/

The below code works when an array of public suffixes has been created already. Simply call

```
$domain = get_private_domain("www.google.co.uk");
```

with the remaining code...

```
// find some way to parse the above list of public suffix
// then add them to a PHP array
$suffix = [... all valid public suffix ...];

function get_public_suffix($host) {
  $parts = split("\.", $host);
  while (count($parts) > 0) {
    if (is_public_suffix(join(".", $parts)))
      return join(".", $parts);

    array_shift($parts);
  }

  return false;
}

function is_public_suffix($host) {
  global $suffix;
  return isset($suffix[$host]);
}

function get_private_domain($host) {
  $public = get_public_suffix($host);
  $public_parts = split("\.", $public);
  $all_parts = split("\.", $host);

  $private = [];

  for ($x = 0; $x < count($public_parts); ++$x) 
    $private[] = array_pop($all_parts);

  if (count($all_parts) > 0)
    $private[] = array_pop($all_parts);

  return join(".", array_reverse($private));
}
```

Comment: As per my testing,  parse_url needs a well formed URL. If you just give 'www.someDomain.com/path' then it will return null. So it expects a protocols (like http or https) to be present.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getTrimmedUrl($link)
{
    $str = str_replace(["www.","https://","http://"],[''],$link);
    $link = explode("/",$str);
    return strtolower($link[0]);                
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
echo implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $domain), -2, 2))
```

Comment: does not work for http://google.co.uk/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html

Answer (score 1):

parse_url didn't work for me.  It only returned the path.  Switching to basics using php5.3+:

```
$url  = str_replace('http://', '', strtolower( $s->website));
if (strpos($url, '/'))  $url = strstr($url, '/', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edited for you:

```
function getHost($Address) { 
    $parseUrl = parse_url(trim($Address));
    $host = trim($parseUrl['host'] ? $parseUrl['host'] : array_shift(explode('/', $parseUrl['path'], 2))); 

    $parts = explode( '.', $host );
    $num_parts = count($parts);

    if ($parts[0] == "www") {
        for ($i=1; $i < $num_parts; $i++) { 
            $h .= $parts[$i] . '.';
        }
    }else {
        for ($i=0; $i < $num_parts; $i++) { 
            $h .= $parts[$i] . '.';
        }
    }
    return substr($h,0,-1);
}
```

All type url (www.domain.ltd, sub1.subn.domain.ltd will result to : domain.ltd.

Answer (score 1):

None of this solutions worked for me when I use this test cases:

```
public function getTestCases(): array
{
    return [
        //input                              expected
        ['http://google.com/dhasjkdas',      'google.com'],
        ['https://google.com/dhasjkdas',     'google.com'],
        ['https://www.google.com/dhasjkdas', 'google.com'],
        ['http://www.google.com/dhasjkdas',  'google.com'],
        ['www.google.com/dhasjkdas',         'google.com'],
        ['google.com/dhasjkdas',             'google.com'],
    ];
}
```

but wrapping this answer into function worked in all cases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65659814/5884988

Answer (score 0):

This will generally work very well if the input URL is not total junk.  It removes the subdomain.

```
$host = parse_url( $Row->url, PHP_URL_HOST );
$parts = explode( '.', $host );
$parts = array_reverse( $parts );
$domain = $parts[1].'.'.$parts[0];
```

**Example**

Input: `http://www2.website.com:8080/some/file/structure?some=parameters`

Output: `website.com`

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers of **worldofjr** and **Alix Axel** into one small function that will handle most use-cases:

```
function get_url_hostname($url) {

    $parse = parse_url($url);
    return str_ireplace('www.', '', $parse['host']);

}

get_url_hostname('http://www.google.com/example/path/file.html'); // google.com
```

Comment: this is limited solution

Answer (score 0):

Try using URI package from The PHP League: https://github.com/thephpleague/uri

```
use League\Uri\UriTemplate;

$template = 'https://api.twitter.com:443/{version}/search/{term:1}/{term}/{?q*,limit}#title';
$defaultVariables = ['version' => '1.1'];
$params = [
    'term' => 'john',
    'q' => ['a', 'b'],
    'limit' => '10',
];

$uriTemplate = new UriTemplate($template, $defaultVariables);
$uri = $uriTemplate->expand($params);
// $uri is a League\Uri\Uri object

echo $uri->getScheme();
echo $uri->getHost();
echo $uri->getAuthority();
echo $uri->getPath();
echo $uri->getQuery();
echo $uri->getFragment();
echo $uri;
```

Answer (score -7):

Just use as like following ...

```
<?php
   echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
?>
```

Comment: This is assuming the server is the url you want to retrieve the domain from. That's not the case.