# Going where PHP parse_url() doesn't - Parsing only the domain

Tags: php, dns

PHP's parse_url() has a host field, which includes the full host.  I'm looking for the most reliable (and least costly) way to only return the domain and TLD.

Given the examples:

- http://www.google.com/foo, parse_url() returns www.google.com for host
- http://www.google.co.uk/foo, parse_url() returns www.google.co.uk for host

I am looking for only **google.com** or **google.co.uk**.  I have contemplated a table of valid TLD's/suffixes and only allowing those and one word.  Would you do it any other way?  Does anyone know of a pre-canned valid REGEX for this sort of thing?

Comment: You've made a judgement up front that I'm not sure will hold well enough, that is you can tell what portion of a host is the domain that is of interest, is it really the TLD?

Comment: For instance just about any dyndns domain name would seem to be blocked if you only look at the standard domain name. To stop spam from the domain of www.mysite.isa-geek.org, or just mysite.isa-geek.org would you care if you blocked all of isa-geek.org?

Comment: Yes, I would be fine blocking isa-geek.org in this case.  I'm most concerned with foo.[suffix] where [suffix] is the tld or combo of standard suffixes . tld (co.uk)

Comment: see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288810/get-the-subdomain-from-a-url/14688913#14688913

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39307593/530553

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about something like that?

```
function getDomain($url) {
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}
```

Will extract the domain name using the classic `parse_url` and then look for a valid domain without any subdomain (www being a subdomain). Won't work on things like 'localhost'. Will return false if it didn't match anything.

**// Edit:**

Try it out with:

```
echo getDomain('http://www.google.com/test.html') . '<br/>';
echo getDomain('https://news.google.co.uk/?id=12345') . '<br/>';
echo getDomain('http://my.subdomain.google.com/directory1/page.php?id=abc') . '<br/>';
echo getDomain('https://testing.multiple.subdomain.google.co.uk/') . '<br/>';
echo getDomain('http://nothingelsethan.com') . '<br/>';
```

And it should return:

```
google.com
google.co.uk
google.com
google.co.uk
nothingelsethan.com
```

Of course, it won't return anything if it doesn't get through [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url), so make sure it's a well-formed URL.

**// Addendum:**

Alnitak is right. The solution presented above will work in **most** cases but not necessarily all and needs to be maintained to make sure, for example, that their aren't new TLD with .morethan6characters and so on. The only reliable way of extracting the domain is to use a maintained list such as http://publicsuffix.org/. It's more painful at first but easier and more robust on the long-term. You need to make sure you understand the pros and cons of each method and how it fits with your project.

Comment: Any reason why somebody down-voted this? We could try to improve the answer if it's not right or if there's something to be added.

Comment: I down voted this -  it's not the right answer.  It is impossible to definitively figure out the "domain part" (i.e. ignoring "www", etc) with just a simple regexp.  See the related questions and their answers linked elsewhere.  The publicsuffix.org list is the most reliable method.

Comment: I don't understand why this works but it does. Also, it should be `[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,62}`, right?

Comment: Not work for new tlds like http://test.download or short domains like http://vet.kr.ir

Answer (score 6):

Currently the only "right" way to do this is to use a list such as that maintained at http://publicsuffix.org/

BTW, this question is also pretty much a duplicate of:

- [Can I improve this regex check for valid domain names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399932/can-this-domain-name-regular-expression-be-refactored-further)
- [Get the subdomain from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288810/get-the-subdomain-from-a-url)

There are standardisation efforts at IETF looking at DNS methods of declaring whether a particular node in the DNS tree is used for "public" registrations, but they're in their early stages of development.  All of the popular non-IE browsers use the publicsuffix.org list.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a very nice port of Python's tldextract module http://w-shadow.com/blog/2012/08/28/tldextract - this goes beyond parse_url and allows you to actually get the domain/tld out, without the subdomain.

From the module website:

```
$components = tldextract('http://www.bbc.co.uk');
echo $components->subdomain; // www
echo $components->domain;    // bbc
echo $components->tld;       // co.uk
```

Answer (score 1):

Dug this up from a related post, for the idea of keeping a table:  http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/src/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1

I'd rather not do that though.

Comment: i'm afraid using that list is the only way. there's too much variety in ccTLDs to write solution which will do them all.

Comment: The link works again but just redirects to https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat which is now the home for this feature ("Public Suffix List")

Answer (score 1):

You need package that uses [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), only in this way you can correctly extract domains with two-, third-level TLDs (co.uk, a.bg, b.bg, etc.) and multilevel subdomains. Regex, parse_url() or string functions will never produce absolutely correct result.

I recomend use [TLD Extract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract). Here example of code:

```
$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();

$result = $extract->parse('http://www.google.co.uk/foo');
$result->getSubdomain(); // will return (string) 'www'
$result->getHostname(); // will return (string) 'google'
$result->getSuffix(); // will return (string) 'co.uk'
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return (string) 'google.co.uk'
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it depends on your specific use case, but generally speaking I would not use a table lookup for TLDs. New TLDs come out and you usually don't want to maintain them anywhere. Just ask me how often my firstname@lastname.name has been rejected because of shortsightedness.

I guess I could help better if I knew why you not want the www? Do you need it for emails? You can query for MX records in such cases to verify it (eventually) accepts mails.

You may also find help with PHP functions dealing with DNS records to find out more information about them, see http://php.net/dns_get_record for example.

Comment: I'm looking to use it make a blacklist of spammer domains and prevent people from using wildcard DNS to get around it.  It's more for blog or comment spam than email.

Answer (score 0):

Just a proof, assuming the allowed tlds are memorized into an hash.
The code can be shortened a lot.

```
<?php
    $urlCompoments=parse_url($theUrl);
    $chunk=explode('.',$urlComponents['host']);

    $tldIndex = count($chunk-1); // assume last chunk is tld
    $maxTldLen = 2; // assuming a tld can be in the form .com or .co.uk
    $cursor=1;
    $found=false;
    while(($cursor<=$maxTldLen) or $found) {
      $tls = implode('.',array_slice($chunk, -$cursor));
      $found=isset($tldSuffixesAllowed[$tld]);
      $cursor++;
    }
    if ($found){
       $tld=implode('.',array_slice($chunk, -$cursor));
    } else {
       // domain not recognized, do wathever you want
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

There is a really easy solution to this:

```
function get_domain($url) {
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  return array_pop(explode('.', $pieces['host'], 2));
}
```

Surely this will work?