# Looking for regex/code for hostname/machine name validation

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, network-programming, dns, hostname

Looking for hostname validation regex.

[Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address)

In that link gentlemen propose a decent regex. I have a few problems/questions with that:

- On windows computers/networks names
  like `1abcd` are allowed (verified on
  our local network)
- In the proposed regex the dot might appear only once. I'd assume
  that `abc.def.gh` is a valid hostname
  as well, isn't it.

Strange, but also couldn't find any .NET class that can validate hostname string (is it the situation?). Any advice will be highly appreciated.

**Update**: for any class/method proposal - please advice something that will work both in .NET/C# and SilverLight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the proposed regex the dot might
> appear only once. I'd assume that
> abc.def.gh is a valid hostname as
> well, isn't it.

The dot MAY appear more than once. Test the regular expression [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/) and you will see that it matches.

Relevant fragment of the regular expression (first part is):

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*
```

> On windows computers/networks names
> like 1abcd are allowed (verified on
> our local network)

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname):

> The original specification of
> hostnames in [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952), mandated that
> labels could not start with a digit or
> with a hyphen, and must not end with a
> hyphen. However, a subsequent
> specification ([RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123)) permitted
> hostname labels to start with digits.

I referred to [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952). I will try to update the regular expression for hostnames to be compliant with [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123).

Comment: Another thing to consider is that segments may be no more than 63 characters in length and the entire hostname cannot exceed 253 characters in length.

Answer (score 3):

Is [Uri.CheckHostName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.checkhostname.aspx) a method that can help you ?
If the hostname is not recognize, the result will be ["Unknown"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urihostnametype.aspx).

Comment: That method name looked promising to me till today morning. However, names like "9999999" pass (should they?). Also names like "1.3" pass as well (should they?).

Comment: It seems to be valid hostname, according to what I understand in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names)

Comment: The method doesn't work in Silverlight and the code is supposed to serve SL platform as well.

Comment: I'd see [Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx) in Silverlight (but never use). It resolve the hostname and launch ArgumentException if it's not a valid hostname.

On the right there is an other question [validate hostname string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532053/validate-hostname-string-in-python) with this regex "(?!-)[A-Z\d-]{1,63}(?<!-)$"

Answer (score 0):

`(?i)(?=.{5,20}$)^(([a-z\d]|[a-z\d][a-z\d\-]*[a-z\d])\.)*([a-z\d]|[a-z\d][a-z\d\-]*[a-z\d])$`

Explanation:

`(?i)`   - Ignore case

`(?=.{5,20}$)`   - Limit the string length within 5 to 20 characters.

`^(([a-z\d]|[a-z\d][a-z\d\-]*[a-z\d])\.)*([a-z\d]|[a-z\d][a-z\d\-]*[a-z\d])$`   - Accepts any alphabets and numeric along with hyphen and dot