# Valid domain name regex

Tags: python, regex

how should be valid domain name regex which full fill following criteria.

1. each label max 63 characters long minimum 1 characters
2. contains numbers, letters and '-', But
3. should not start and end with '-'
4. max domain name length 255 characters minimum 1.

for example

some of valid combinations:

```
a
a.com
aa-bb.b
```

I created this `^(([a-z0-9]){1,63}\.?){1,255}$`

But currently its not validating '-' part as required (it's , missing)

Is there any way?

plz correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: use urlparse! Regex is not the answer to everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

and mandatory to end with '.' :
Here i found the solution

```
"^(((([A-Za-z0-9]+){1,63}\.)|(([A-Za-z0-9]+(\-)+[A-Za-z0-9]+){1,63}\.))+){1,255}$"
```

Comment: It doesn't have to end with a period. Mind explaining? A period normally comes in the last 2-4 characters of the domain, before the domain extension.

Comment: Yes, It is optional to have period at end. Needs improvement accordingly.

Comment: I decided to go with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532053/validate-a-hostname-string

Answer (score 2):

This expression should meet all the requirements:

`^(?=.{1,255}$)(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9\-]{1,63}(\.[A-Za-z0-9\-]{1,63})*\.?(?<!-)$`

- uses lookahead for total character length
- domain can optionally end with a `.`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library, e.g. validators. Or you can copy [their code](https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/validators/domain.html#domain):

#### Installation

```
pip install validators
```

#### Usage

```
import validators
if validators.domain('example.com')
    print('this domain is valid')
```

In the unlikely case you find a mistake, you can fix and report the error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}\.?)+(\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)){1,255}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex for parsing domain names, use [urllib.parse](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

If you need to find valid domain names in HTML then split the text of the page with a regex `[ <>]` and then parse each resulting string with urllib.parse.

Comment: urllib.parse will not ensure a valid domain name.  the `netloc` could contain "localhost" or a false-positive of a malformed url ( e.g. "http://example", "http://malformed" )

Answer (score 0):

Use the | operator in your RE followed by the '-'.. ensure you escape the literal '-' with \

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex try to look at `urlparse`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

It's fairly simple to learn and a lot better and comfortable to use.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: `urlparse()` accepts invalid domain names, try `urlparse("http://www.......example......com")`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
^(([a-z0-9]\-*[a-z0-9]*){1,63}\.?){1,255}$
```