# Laravel - Validate email domain

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I want to validate domain when user enter invalid domain eg theemail@invaliddomainame.com

```
$createAccount_validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

        'username'=>'required|min:6',
        'email'=>'required|email|unique:userTable)',

]);
```

Currently API of email validation is premium so I don't want to use.

Comment: So, you want to exclude a list of email hosts?

Comment: @Jerodev I want to validate when user enter invalid domain which not exists.

Comment: @user3151197 That's quite complex. You'd have to do a WHOIS, a query for MX records, a query for A records, etc. Would take several seconds to run, most likely, and wouldn't be particularly reliable... and you'd still wind up with lots of valid domains but invalid emails still. If you need a real email, send a verification email to it with a link to click.

Comment: @ceejayoz if laravel allow me I can validate domain get_headers.

Comment: @user3151197 While possible with a Laravel custom validator, that won't work. Plenty of emails come from valid domains that don't have a website on the domain.

Comment: What does "validating" a domain even mean? There are way too many variables and as said the only way to know if an email is functional is to send an email to it.

Answer (score 0):

Under `~app/Http/Requests/UserRequest.php` you can use a regex for the `email_domain` field like

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        'email_domain' => [
            'required', 
            'regex:/^(?!\-)(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d\-]{0,61})?[a-zA-Z\d]\.){1,126}(?!\d+)[a-zA-Z\d]{1,63}$/',
        ]
    ];
}
```

[This pattern I'm using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16491074/5675325) conforms with most of the rules defined in the specs. Notice that in this case we need to use `/` before and after.