# PHP preg match *.domain.com or *.domain.co.uk

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using this code to preg match for *.domain.com but need it changed to also include foreign domains which have a few periods like *.domain.co.uk. Any helps appreciated thanks

```
if (trim(preg_match('!^https?://([^/]+\.)?domain\.com(/|#|$)!i', $documentLink->getAttribute('href'))))
```

Just an update that i'm looking to match *.domain.(any TLD) not just co.uk

Thanks

Comment: Maybe check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399932/can-i-improve-this-regex-check-for-valid-domain-names

Comment: What you are going to do with http://www.nic.tr and http://www.odtu.edu.tr and http://www.cosmos.1.bg and http://www.cosmos.bg/ ?

Comment: Note that http://cosmos1.bg is ccTLD. There does not exist something like http://1.bg.

Comment: I tested this "(preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) " and it gets nic.tr odtu.edu.tr, the only domain it doesn't pickup is cosmos.1.bg, i'm not good with regex but I think it's because of the single character in the middle. What change can I make? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
!^https?://([^/]+\.)?domain(.com|co.uk)(/|#|$)!i
```

Comment: .co.uk was an example I need to get any *.domain.(any tld)

Answer (score 0):

```
!^(https?://)?([\w-]+\.)?domain(\.[a-z]{2,5})+(/|#|$)!i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
!^https?://([^/]+\.)?domain[.a-z]+(/|#|$)!i
```