# php preg_match or php regex to find word

Tags: php

how can I write some preg_match() or any other condition to find whether the URL have "php" in the second place. Eg url below "http://a.com/php/abcpdf/".

If the URL have "/php/" in the second place my condition should execute else not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP preg match \*.domain.com or \*.domain.co.uk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782591/php-preg-match-domain-com-or-domain-co-uk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to parse the URL data and process the URI path accordingly.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://a.com/php/abcpdf/';

$url_data = parse_url($url);

if(strpos(trim($url_data['path'],'/') . "/","php/") !== false){
    echo "exists"; // your task
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/XQlF1

Answer (score 0):

this should match what you need

```
preg_match("#^/php/#", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])
```