# Regular Expression for Domain names

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I am trying to validate a csv file of domain names (eg. @google.com, @xyz.co.uk, @xyz.edu etc.)

I am using the following Regular Expression:

```
Regex(@"@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Is there scope for improvement on the above?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399932/can-i-improve-this-regex-check-for-valid-domain-names

Comment: This is a decent first line of defense, but it's too easy to fool *intentionally*. Take a look at the accepted answer of the linked question, it is a much better approach.

Comment: I tried to do [e-mail validation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) once, and as you can see, there are many different regex's (especially after the `@` symbol) you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Familiarize yourself with some dedicated [sites](http://regexlib.com/).

Pick a solution that does NOT require constant maintenance.  Your own regex looks pretty good for some applications where you do not expect outright attacks.

See also the answer linked by @lna in a comment.

Comment: OK. But with my regular expression above... I am able to return abc@gmail.com as True... which is incorrect...

Comment: Because it is not anchored.  Add `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end, if you want the whole input string to match and not just any substring.