# Regular expression to extract domain name from any domain

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract the domain name from a string in C#. You don't necessarily have to use a RegEx but we should be able to extract `yourdomain.com` from all of the following:

```
yourdomain.com
www.yourdomain.com
http://www.yourdomain.com
http://www.yourdomain.com/
store.yourdomain.com
http://store.yourdomain.com
whatever.youdomain.com
*.yourdomain.com
```

Also, any TLD is acceptable, so replace all the above with `.net`, `.org`, `'co'uk`, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. If no scheme present (no colon in string), prepend "http://" to make it a valid URL.
2. Pass string to [Uri constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492.aspx).
3. Access the Uri's [Host property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx).

Now you have the hostname. What exactly you consider the ‘domain name’ of a given hostname is a debatable point. I'm guessing you don't simply mean everything after the first dot.

It's not possible to distinguish hostnames like ‘whatever.youdomain.com’ from domains-in-an-SLD like ‘warwick.ac.uk’ from just the strings. Indeed, there is even a bit of grey area about what is and isn't a public SLD, given the efforts of some registrars to carve out their own niches.

A common approach is to maintain a big list of SLDs and other suffixes used by unrelated entities. This is what web browsers do to stop unwanted public cookie sharing. Once you've found a public suffix, you could add the one nearest prefix in the host name split by dots to get the highest-level entity responsible for the given hostname, if that's what you want. Suffix lists are hell to maintain, but you can piggy-back on [someone else's efforts](http://publicsuffix.org/).

Alternatively, if your app has the time and network connection to do it, it could start sniffing for information on the hostname. eg. it could do a whois query for the hostname, and keep looking at each parent until it got a result and that would be the domain name of the lowest-level entity responsible for the given hostname.

Or, if all that's too much work, you could try just chopping off any leading ‘www.’ present!

Comment: There is an opensource C# library that uses publicsuffix.org to parse domains, here: http://code.google.com/p/domainname-parser/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying this yourself. Using regulator and a regex cheat sheet.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/

http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

Also find some good info on Regular Expressions at [coding horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001016.html).

Comment: I've been trying this myself for about an hour now. Thanks for the links though.

Answer (score 0):

A regex doesn't really fit your requirement of "*any* TLD", since the format and number of TLDs is quite large and continually in flux. If you limited your scope to:

```
(?<domain>[^\.]+\.([A-Z]+$|co\.[A-Z]$))
```

You would catch .anything and .co.anything, which I imagine covers most realistic cases...

Comment: I don't really need ANY TLD, I do need the most popular ones though.

Comment: This regex covers every popular TLD (.anything and .co.anything). It does assume you'll strip off the ending slash if there is one.

Comment: Depends on your definition of popular and what parts of the world your site generally serves

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399250/going-where-php-parseurl-doesnt-parsing-only-the-domain/399316#399316). It was for PHP but you'll easily get the regex out of the 4-5 lines of PHP and you can benefit from the discussion that followed (see [Alnitak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399250/going-where-php-parseurl-doesnt-parsing-only-the-domain/401456#401456)).