# How to check what is wrong in domain URL in C#

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

How to check what is wrong in domain URL in C#

I want to updated domain URL when invalid domain enter.

```
Input Put of Domain:          OutPut Like

1)http:/localhost:1234/------>http://localhost:1234/
2)http://localhost:1234------>http://localhost:1234/
3)http:localhost:1234/------->http://localhost:1234/
4)http:localhost:1234-------->http://localhost:1234/
5)localhost:1234/------------>http://localhost:1234/
6)localhost:1234------------->http://localhost:1234/
```

Also above all test cases with **HTTPS**

May be need add more test cases.

I have code of nopCommerece for warning but it's use only current store .

How I develop a code for enter domain is valid or not and return valid domain.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the question is you want to take in a given URL and output a correction. At the very minumum you are looking for the string "localhost:1234". You could use a regular expression to check for the existence of this string. If true, output "http://localhost:1234/"

The regular express is "/localhost:1234/g" and can be found here: http://regexr.com/3e2n8

To check this regular expression in C# you will code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/localhost:1234/g");
    Match match = regex.Match("http:/localhost:1234/"); // your given string
    if (match.Success)
    {
        // your given string contains localhost:1234
    }
```

Comment: If I have http:/www.test.com then?
As mention in my question domain url so not use only in  local

Comment: Hello @KalpeshBoghara - your original question does not include that. You will need to update your original question. Please state your question clearly.

Answer (score -3):

In any domain name the following are important:

www..com:

portnumber is 80 by default

but still, to check and get the Exception, use this URL,

[Best way to determine if a domain name would be a valid in a "hosts" file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967516/best-way-to-determine-if-a-domain-name-would-be-a-valid-in-a-hosts-file)

Comment: get the exception stack to know what is wrong in the statement