# Host of an NSURL without the subdomains

Tags: cocoa, subdomain, nsurl

How can you **get the host of an NSURL without the subdomains**?

Here are some inputs.
The part that should remain is in bold, and what should be stripped is in italic:

> **server.com**
>   *www.***server.com**
>   *media.***server.com**
>   *host1.media.***server.com**

So far, sounds very easy to implement.
But it should also correctly handle the following inputs, as well as any weird case I didn't think about that is commonly accepted or specified in any relevant RFC.

> **server.co.uk**
>   *media.***server.co.uk**
>   **127.0.0.1**
>   ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Extract domain name from a host name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825694/extract-domain-name-from-a-host-name) This problem doesn't seem to have an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the hard question, but if you're matching a URL to a white list of specific domains (like I was when I found this question) you can use code like this to check:

```
NSArray *domainsForVideo = @[@"youtube.com",
                             @"youtu.be",
                             @"videoschool.pvt.k12.md.us",
                             @"vimeo.com"];

NSString *host = [url host]; //where URL is some NSURL object

BOOL hostMatches = NO;

for (NSString *testHost in domainsForVideo) {
    if ([[host lowercaseString] isEqualToString:testHost]) hostMatches = YES;  // matches youtube.com exectly

    NSString *testSubdomain = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@",testHost];  // matches www.youtube.com but not fakeyoutube.com
    if ([[host lowercaseString] rangeOfString:testSubdomain].location != NSNotFound) hostMatches = YES;
}

if (hostMatches) {
    // this is a Video URL
}
```