# Get domain name (not subdomain) in php

Tags: php, regex, domain-name

I have a URL which can be any of the following formats:

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
http://example.com/foo
http://example.com/foo/bar
www.example.com
example.com
foo.example.com
www.foo.example.com
foo.bar.example.com
http://foo.bar.example.com/foo/bar
example.net/foo/bar
```

Essentially, I need to be able to match any normal URL. How can I extract `example.com`  (or .net, whatever the tld happens to be. I need this to work with any TLD.) from all of these via a single regex?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399250/going-where-php-parse-url-doesnt-parsing-only-the-domain

Comment: For two-segment top-level domains, you can go through this : link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201194/php-getting-domain-name-from-subdomain

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Well you can use `parse_url` to get the host:

```
$info = parse_url($url);
$host = $info['host'];
```

Then, you can do some fancy stuff to get only the TLD and the Host

```
$host_names = explode(".", $host);
$bottom_host_name = $host_names[count($host_names)-2] . "." . $host_names[count($host_names)-1];
```

Not very elegant, but should work.

---

If you want an explanation, here it goes:

First we grab everything between the scheme (`http://`, etc), by using `parse_url`'s capabilities to... well.... parse URL's. :)

Then we take the host name, and separate it into an array based on where the periods fall, so `test.world.hello.myname` would become:

```
array("test", "world", "hello", "myname");
```

After that, we take the number of elements in the array (4).

Then, we subtract 2 from it to get the second to last string (the hostname, or `example`, in your example)

Then, we subtract 1 from it to get the last string (because array keys start at 0), also known as the TLD

Then we combine those two parts with a period, and you have your base host name.

Comment: What about two-segment top-level domains like `co.uk`?

Comment: The only option is to fetch all TLDs from a reliable source and work with those.

Comment: @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL Exactly, that list can be found at: http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) get host in one line

Comment: Downvoted since this does not support domains ccTLDs.

Comment: That "fancy stuff" is just wrong for many cases, like any 2LD.

Comment: You can use [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) for the last step: `$bottom_host_name = implode ( '.', array_slice( explode( '.', $host ), -2 ) );`

Answer (score 18):

It is not possible to get the domain name without using a TLD list to compare with as their exist many cases with completely the same structure and length:

```
 nas.db.de (Subdomain)
 bbc.co.uk (Top-Level-Domain)

 www.uk.com (Subdomain)
 big.uk.com (Second-Level-Domain)
```

Mozilla's public suffix list should be the best option as it is used by all [major browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Suffix_List):
https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat

Feel free to use my function:

```
function tld_list($cache_dir=null) {
    // we use "/tmp" if $cache_dir is not set
    $cache_dir = isset($cache_dir) ? $cache_dir : sys_get_temp_dir();
    $lock_dir = $cache_dir . '/public_suffix_list_lock/';
    $list_dir = $cache_dir . '/public_suffix_list/';
    // refresh list all 30 days
    if (file_exists($list_dir) && @filemtime($list_dir) + 2592000 > time()) {
        return $list_dir;
    }
    // use exclusive lock to avoid race conditions
    if (!file_exists($lock_dir) && @mkdir($lock_dir)) {
        // read from source
        $list = @fopen('https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat', 'r');
        if ($list) {
            // the list is older than 30 days so delete everything first
            if (file_exists($list_dir)) {
                foreach (glob($list_dir . '*') as $filename) {
                    unlink($filename);
                }
                rmdir($list_dir);
            }
            // now set list directory with new timestamp
            mkdir($list_dir);
            // read line-by-line to avoid high memory usage
            while ($line = fgets($list)) {
                // skip comments and empty lines
                if ($line[0] == '/' || !$line) {
                    continue;
                }
                // remove wildcard
                if ($line[0] . $line[1] == '*.') {
                    $line = substr($line, 2);
                }
                // remove exclamation mark
                if ($line[0] == '!') {
                    $line = substr($line, 1);
                }
                // reverse TLD and remove linebreak
                $line = implode('.', array_reverse(explode('.', (trim($line)))));
                // we split the TLD list to reduce memory usage
                touch($list_dir . $line);
            }
            fclose($list);
        }
        @rmdir($lock_dir);
    }
    // repair locks (should never happen)
    if (file_exists($lock_dir) && mt_rand(0, 100) == 0 && @filemtime($lock_dir) + 86400 < time()) {
        @rmdir($lock_dir);
    }
    return $list_dir;
}
function get_domain($url=null) {
    // obtain location of public suffix list
    $tld_dir = tld_list();
    // no url = our own host
    $url = isset($url) ? $url : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    // add missing scheme      ftp://            http:// ftps://   https://
    $url = !isset($url[5]) || ($url[3] != ':' && $url[4] != ':' && $url[5] != ':') ? 'http://' . $url : $url;
    // remove "/path/file.html", "/:80", etc.
    $url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    // replace absolute domain name by relative (http://www.dns-sd.org/TrailingDotsInDomainNames.html)
    $url = trim($url, '.');
    // check if TLD exists
    $url = explode('.', $url);
    $parts = array_reverse($url);
    foreach ($parts as $key => $part) {
        $tld = implode('.', $parts);
        if (file_exists($tld_dir . $tld)) {
            return !$key ? '' : implode('.', array_slice($url, $key - 1));
        }
        // remove last part
        array_pop($parts);
    }
    return '';
}
```

What it makes special:

- it accepts every input like URLs, hostnames or domains with- or without scheme
- the list is downloaded row-by-row to avoid high memory usage
- it creates a new file per TLD in a cache folder so `get_domain()` only needs to check through `file_exists()` if it exists so it does not need to include a huge database on every request like [TLDExtract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract) does it.
- the list will be automatically updated every 30 days

Test:

```
$urls = array(
    'http://www.example.com',// example.com
    'http://subdomain.example.com',// example.com
    'http://www.example.uk.com',// example.uk.com
    'http://www.example.co.uk',// example.co.uk
    'http://www.example.com.ac',// example.com.ac
    'http://example.com.ac',// example.com.ac
    'http://www.example.accident-prevention.aero',// example.accident-prevention.aero
    'http://www.example.sub.ar',// sub.ar
    'http://www.congresodelalengua3.ar',// congresodelalengua3.ar
    'http://congresodelalengua3.ar',// congresodelalengua3.ar
    'http://www.example.pvt.k12.ma.us',// example.pvt.k12.ma.us
    'http://www.example.lib.wy.us',// example.lib.wy.us
    'com',// empty
    '.com',// empty
    'http://big.uk.com',// big.uk.com
    'uk.com',// empty
    'www.uk.com',// www.uk.com
    '.uk.com',// empty
    'stackoverflow.com',// stackoverflow.com
    '.foobarfoo',// empty
    '',// empty
    false,// empty
    ' ',// empty
    1,// empty
    'a',// empty    
);
```

Recent version with explanations (German):
http://www.programmierer-forum.de/domainnamen-ermitteln-t244185.htm

Comment: does it work with localhost and IPs? `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `192.168.1.100`...

Comment: Your question does not make sense as the question is to extract the domain name. What do you want to extract from `localhost`

Comment: Is it that website `uk.com` could set cookies for `big.uk.com`, because latter can be seen as subdomain of first? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Somnium There exist not website `uk.com` because it is an official private sub-domain registry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_sub-domain_registry  So its a subdomain with the status of a TLD.

Comment: You can slightly improve the code by moving `trim($line)` to the top of the loop in `tld_list` function, so it would skip empty lines

Answer (score 16):

My solution in https://gist.github.com/pocesar/5366899

and the tests are here http://codepad.viper-7.com/GAh1tP

It works with any TLD, and hideous subdomain patterns (up to 3 subdomains).

There's a test included with many domain names.

Won't paste the function here because of the weird indentation for code in StackOverflow (could have fenced code blocks like github)

Comment: Thanks! This is a very clever script that did the job without any lookup.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. How come this answer didn't get more upvotes ?

Comment: This seems to work, but doesn't work for website URLs like: http://foo.bar.example.com/foo/bar

Comment: @Bashevis the coded is intended for hostnames, not URLs, which you can easily extract using `parse_url('http://foo.bar.example.com/foo/bar', PHP_URL_HOST);`

Comment: does not work for `sub.example.co` and return `sub.example.co`

Comment: the best thing is to create a lookup array with all available TLDs from IANA, a lot have been added since 2013 including having support for punycode https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains a bit of manual setup at first, but performant, and strictly compliant to the list

Answer (score 7):

```
echo getDomainOnly("http://example.com/foo/bar");

function getDomainOnly($host){
    $host = strtolower(trim($host));
    $host = ltrim(str_replace("http://","",str_replace("https://","",$host)),"www.");
    $count = substr_count($host, '.');
    if($count === 2){
        if(strlen(explode('.', $host)[1]) > 3) $host = explode('.', $host, 2)[1];
    } else if($count > 2){
        $host = getDomainOnly(explode('.', $host, 2)[1]);
    }
    $host = explode('/',$host);
    return $host[0];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way to handle this problem is:

```
$second_level_domains_regex = '/\.asn\.au$|\.com\.au$|\.net\.au$|\.id\.au$|\.org\.au$|\.edu\.au$|\.gov\.au$|\.csiro\.au$|\.act\.au$|\.nsw\.au$|\.nt\.au$|\.qld\.au$|\.sa\.au$|\.tas\.au$|\.vic\.au$|\.wa\.au$|\.co\.at$|\.or\.at$|\.priv\.at$|\.ac\.at$|\.avocat\.fr$|\.aeroport\.fr$|\.veterinaire\.fr$|\.co\.hu$|\.film\.hu$|\.lakas\.hu$|\.ingatlan\.hu$|\.sport\.hu$|\.hotel\.hu$|\.ac\.nz$|\.co\.nz$|\.geek\.nz$|\.gen\.nz$|\.kiwi\.nz$|\.maori\.nz$|\.net\.nz$|\.org\.nz$|\.school\.nz$|\.cri\.nz$|\.govt\.nz$|\.health\.nz$|\.iwi\.nz$|\.mil\.nz$|\.parliament\.nz$|\.ac\.za$|\.gov\.za$|\.law\.za$|\.mil\.za$|\.nom\.za$|\.school\.za$|\.net\.za$|\.co\.uk$|\.org\.uk$|\.me\.uk$|\.ltd\.uk$|\.plc\.uk$|\.net\.uk$|\.sch\.uk$|\.ac\.uk$|\.gov\.uk$|\.mod\.uk$|\.mil\.uk$|\.nhs\.uk$|\.police\.uk$/';
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$domain = explode('.', $domain);
$domain = array_reverse($domain);
if (preg_match($second_level_domains_regex, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    $domain = "$domain[2].$domain[1].$domain[0]";
} else {
    $domain = "$domain[1].$domain[0]";
}
```

Comment: Now it works for second-level-domains, such as .co.uk @Spode

Comment: No, it works for **some** 2LDs certainly not all of them... Try with `anything.gouv.fr`... And then you have 3LDs, 4LDs, etc.

Comment: Those are new ones created after this was answered, of course you would have to update the $second_level_domains_regex if you want to support them all

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using [TLDExtract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract) library for all operations with domain name.

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
$onlyHostName = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', parse_url($link, PHP_URL_HOST)), -2));
```

Using `https://subdomain.domain.com/some/path` as example

`parse_url($link, PHP_URL_HOST)` returns `subdomain.domain.com`

`explode('.', parse_url($link, PHP_URL_HOST))` then breaks `subdomain.domain.com` into an array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "subdomain"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "domain"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "com"
}
```

`array_slice` then slices the array so only the last 2 values are in the array (signified by the `-2`):

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "domain"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "com"
}
```

`implode` then combines those two array values back together, ultimately giving you the result of `domain.com`

***Note:*** this will only work when end domain you're expecting only has one `.` in it, like `something.domain.com` or `else.something.domain.net`

*It will not work for `something.domain.co.uk` where you would expect `domain.co.uk`*

Comment: try to offer an explanation next to the code. The poster should learn what he is doing. Otherwise he will create moer questions with the same issue.

Comment: @Ameoo I'm not likely to ask the question again, please note this is over two years old

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to extract subdomain from a host:

1. The first method that is more accurate is to use a database of tlds (like [public_suffix_list.dat](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat)) and match domain with it. This is a little heavy in some cases. There are some PHP classes for using it like [php-domain-parser](https://github.com/jeremykendall/php-domain-parser) and [TLDExtract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract).
2. The second way is not as accurate as the first one, but is very fast and it can give the correct answer in many case, I wrote this function for it:

   ```
   function get_domaininfo($url) {
       // regex can be replaced with parse_url
       preg_match("/^(https|http|ftp):\/\/(.*?)\//", "$url/" , $matches);
       $parts = explode(".", $matches[2]);
       $tld = array_pop($parts);
       $host = array_pop($parts);
       if ( strlen($tld) == 2 && strlen($host) <= 3 ) {
           $tld = "$host.$tld";
           $host = array_pop($parts);
       }

       return array(
           'protocol' => $matches[1],
           'subdomain' => implode(".", $parts),
           'domain' => "$host.$tld",
           'host'=>$host,'tld'=>$tld
       );
   }
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   print_r(get_domaininfo('http://mysubdomain.domain.co.uk/index.php'));
   ```

   Returns:

   ```
   Array
   (
       [protocol] => https
       [subdomain] => mysubdomain
       [domain] => domain.co.uk
       [host] => domain
       [tld] => co.uk
   )
   ```

Comment: There are too many false assomptions, try with `print_r(get_domaininfo('http://mysubdomain.domain.gouv.fr/index.php'));` it will not give correct result ("TLD" should be `gouv.fr` there and not `fr`). Also it does not work for 3LD, 4LD, etc. like in .US

Comment: @PatrickMevzek For these cases, first method should be used. it is up to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function I wrote to grab the domain without subdomain(s), regardless of whether the domain is using a ccTLD or a new style long TLD, etc...  There is no lookup or huge array of known TLDs, and there's no regex. It can be a lot shorter using the ternary operator and nesting, but I expanded it for readability.

```
// Per Wikipedia: "All ASCII ccTLD identifiers are two letters long, 
// and all two-letter top-level domains are ccTLDs."

function topDomainFromURL($url) {
  $url_parts = parse_url($url);
  $domain_parts = explode('.', $url_parts['host']);
  if (strlen(end($domain_parts)) == 2 ) { 
    // ccTLD here, get last three parts
    $top_domain_parts = array_slice($domain_parts, -3);
  } else {
    $top_domain_parts = array_slice($domain_parts, -2);
  }
  $top_domain = implode('.', $top_domain_parts);
  return $top_domain;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function getDomain($url){
    $pieces = parse_url($url);
    $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
    if(preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)){
        return $regs['domain'];
    }
    return FALSE;
}

echo getDomain("http://example.com"); // outputs 'example.com'
echo getDomain("http://www.example.com"); // outputs 'example.com'
echo getDomain("http://mail.example.co.uk"); // outputs 'example.co.uk'
```

Comment: You should change the potential max TLD length to something higher to acomodate things like http://bueller.academy/

Comment: Would you like to explain how this works?

Answer (score 2):

I had problems with the solution provided by pocesar.
When I would use for instance subdomain.domain.nl it would not return domain.nl. Instead it would return subdomain.domain.nl
Another problem was that domain.com.br would return com.br

I am not sure but i fixed these issues with the following code (i hope it will help someone, if so I am a happy man):

```
function get_domain($domain, $debug = false){
    $original = $domain = strtolower($domain);
    if (filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        return $domain;
    }
    $debug ? print('<strong style="color:green">&raquo;</strong> Parsing: '.$original) : false;
    $arr = array_slice(array_filter(explode('.', $domain, 4), function($value){
        return $value !== 'www';
    }), 0); //rebuild array indexes
    if (count($arr) > 2){
        $count = count($arr);
        $_sub = explode('.', $count === 4 ? $arr[3] : $arr[2]);
        $debug ? print(" (parts count: {$count})") : false;
        if (count($_sub) === 2){ // two level TLD
            $removed = array_shift($arr);
            if ($count === 4){ // got a subdomain acting as a domain
                $removed = array_shift($arr);
            }
            $debug ? print("<br>\n" . '[*] Two level TLD: <strong>' . join('.', $_sub) . '</strong> ') : false;
        }elseif (count($_sub) === 1){ // one level TLD
            $removed = array_shift($arr); //remove the subdomain
            if (strlen($arr[0]) === 2 && $count === 3){ // TLD domain must be 2 letters
                array_unshift($arr, $removed);
            }elseif(strlen($arr[0]) === 3 && $count === 3){
                array_unshift($arr, $removed);
            }else{
                // non country TLD according to IANA
                $tlds = array(
                    'aero',
                    'arpa',
                    'asia',
                    'biz',
                    'cat',
                    'com',
                    'coop',
                    'edu',
                    'gov',
                    'info',
                    'jobs',
                    'mil',
                    'mobi',
                    'museum',
                    'name',
                    'net',
                    'org',
                    'post',
                    'pro',
                    'tel',
                    'travel',
                    'xxx',
                );
                if (count($arr) > 2 && in_array($_sub[0], $tlds) !== false){ //special TLD don't have a country
                    array_shift($arr);
                }
            }
            $debug ? print("<br>\n" .'[*] One level TLD: <strong>'.join('.', $_sub).'</strong> ') : false;
        }else{ // more than 3 levels, something is wrong
            for ($i = count($_sub); $i > 1; $i--){
                $removed = array_shift($arr);
            }
            $debug ? print("<br>\n" . '[*] Three level TLD: <strong>' . join('.', $_sub) . '</strong> ') : false;
        }
    }elseif (count($arr) === 2){
        $arr0 = array_shift($arr);
        if (strpos(join('.', $arr), '.') === false && in_array($arr[0], array('localhost','test','invalid')) === false){ // not a reserved domain
            $debug ? print("<br>\n" .'Seems invalid domain: <strong>'.join('.', $arr).'</strong> re-adding: <strong>'.$arr0.'</strong> ') : false;
            // seems invalid domain, restore it
            array_unshift($arr, $arr0);
        }
    }
    $debug ? print("<br>\n".'<strong style="color:gray">&laquo;</strong> Done parsing: <span style="color:red">' . $original . '</span> as <span style="color:blue">'. join('.', $arr) ."</span><br>\n") : false;
    return join('.', $arr);
}
```

Comment: Your list of gTLDs (that is non ccTLDs) is very much out of date (and already was at the time of your answer)...

Comment: Hi, thanks for noting, but it's just an example, you can update the list and code to your needs.

Comment: For sure, but I was instead trying to put a light on the perils of having hardcoded list and the maintenance that is needed with it, as this is often forgotten. TLDs come and go, even if it does not happen often, particularly now, new gTLDs will come in the following years...

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that works for all domains, including those with second level domains like "co.uk"

```
function strip_subdomains($url){

    # credits to gavingmiller for maintaining this list
    $second_level_domains = file_get_contents("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gavingmiller/second-level-domains/master/SLDs.csv");

    # presume sld first ...
    $possible_sld = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $url), -2));

    # and then verify it
    if (strpos($second_level_domains, $possible_sld)){
        return  implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $url), -3));
    } else {
        return  implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $url), -2));
    }
}
```

Looks like there's a duplicate question here: [delete-subdomain-from-url-string-if-subdomain-is-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809579/delete-subdomain-from-url-string-if-subdomain-is-found/41462559#41462559http://)

Comment: Depending on an external resource like that each time at the moment you need it will create all sorts of problems. Also, there are 3LDs, 4LDs, etc for example in `.US` (grandfathered).

Answer (score 1):

Very late, I see that you marked regex as a keyword and my function works like a charm, so far I haven't found a url that fails:

```
function get_domain_regex($url){
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

if you want one without regex I have this one, which I am sure I also took from this post

```
function get_domain($url){
  $parseUrl = parse_url($url);
  $host = $parseUrl['host'];
  $host_array = explode(".", $host);
  $domain = $host_array[count($host_array)-2] . "." . $host_array[count($host_array)-1];
  return $domain;
}
```

They both work amazing, BUT, this took me a while to realize if the url doesn't start with http:// or https:// it will fail so make sure the url string starts with the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
   preg_match('/(www.)?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/', $yourHost, $matches);

   echo "domain name is: {$matches[0]}\n";
```

this working for majority of domains.

Comment: it fails on these ones

https://subdomain.maindomain.co.au/

Answer (score 0):

This  function will return the domain name without the extension of any url given even if you parse a url without the http:// or https://

You can extend  this code

```
(?:\.co)?(?:\.com)?(?:\.gov)?(?:\.net)?(?:\.org)?(?:\.id)?
```

with more extensions if you want to handle more second level domainnames.

```
    function get_domain_name($url){
      $pieces = parse_url($url);
      $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : $url;
      $domain = strtolower($domain);
      $domain = preg_replace('/.international$/', '.com', $domain);
      if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,90}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
          if (preg_match('/(.*?)((?:\.co)?(?:\.com)?(?:\.gov)?(?:\.net)?(?:\.org)?(?:\.id)?(?:\.asn)?.[a-z]{2,6})$/i', $regs['domain'], $matches)) {
              return $matches[1];
          }else  return $regs['domain'];
      }else{
        return $url;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to achieve the same target and it always works, I hope it will help others.

```
$url          = https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css?ver=2.7.5
$handle       = pathinfo( parse_url( $url )['host'] )['filename'];
$final_handle = substr( $handle , strpos( $handle , '.' ) + 1 );

print_r($final_handle); // fontawesome
```

Comment: I was actually actually hoping this did always work as it appears so elegant, but sadly, it does NOT always work. In fact, simply removing the "use." from the example url makes it fail. `https://fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css?ver=2.7.5` ends up returning `ontawesome`. This code seems to assume there will always be prefix.target.tdl,

Comment: @Bruce Would you please tell me what php version you are using?

Comment: I am using php version 7.2

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution

```
@preg_replace('#\/(.)*#', '', @preg_replace('#^https?://(www.)?#', '', $url))
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply try this:

```
<?php
  $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  preg_match("/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/", $host, $matches);
  echo "domain name is: {$matches[0]}\n";
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure, since `preg_match` needs `()` to capture something. Also, what do you think happens for `www.example.co.uk`? The domain name is `example.co.uk`, not `co.uk`.