# PHP Regexp Non capturing group not working

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get the domain and tld from an http_host by using the following regexp:

```
(?:^|\.)(.+?\.(?:it|com))
```

The regexp works correctly in gskinner.com.

Input:

```
domain.com
www.domain.com
```

Captured groups in both:

```
domain.com
```

However in php the following:

```
preg_match("/(?:^|\.)(.+?\.(?:it|com))/", "www.domain.com", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => www.baloodealer.com
    [1] => www.baloodealer.com
)
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: I'm curious about how you can get "www.baloodealer.com" out of "www.domain.com"

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679618/get-domain-name-not-subdomain-in-php

Comment: ops! sorry for the mess...

Comment: @anubhava Thanks! But actually the question was more about the regex part than the php one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you want the last two parts of the domain?  Before the TLD, don't match just any character:

```
"/(?:^|\.)([^\.]+?\.(?:it|com))$/"
```

(EDIT: anchoring to the end of the string, to fix bug pointed out in comment.)

Comment: This will return "www.com" on "www.company.com"

Comment: @CrayonViolent: D'oh.  Thanks for pointing that out - should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
preg_match("/[^.]+\.(?:it|com)$/", "www.domain.com", $matches);
print_r($matches);

/* output
Array
(
    [0] => domain.com
)
*/
```

Comment: I'm giving this to pob because he answered first. But thanks anyway Crayon!! I always use the dot to be faster but it is do darn evil.

Comment: @DamianoBarbati okay well, pob's regex is flawed. run pob's regex against `www.company.com` and see what happens.