# How to get domain name from URL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables (`url_feed` and `clean_domains`).  I'm trying to copy all of the data from `url_feed` into `clean_domains` and at the same time insert the `domain` from the `url` column.

Also, it will change the `status` from `queued` to `complete` in `url_feed` after it copies the row to `clean_domains`.

Here's what the 2 tables look like:

**url_feed**

```
id | url                                    | matches | networks                    | status
1  | http://whatever.com/example1.php       | 5       | Facebook::Twitter Inc       | queued
2  | http://www.example.com/other-stuff.php | 2       | MySpace::Facebook::Twitter  | queued
3  | http://www.test.com/random-text        | 12      | Instagram::Twitter          | queued
```

**clean_domains**

```
id | domain       | url                                     | matches | networks                    | status
1  | whatever.com | http://whatever.com/example1.php        | 5       | Facebook::Twitter Inc       | queued
2  | example.com  | http://www.example.com/other-stuff.php  | 2       | MySpace::Facebook::Twitter  | queued
3  | test.com     | http://www.test.com/random-text         | 12      | Instagram::Twitter          | queued
```

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","redacted","redacted","redacted");

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO clean_domains
(id,domain,url,matches,networks)
  SELECT
    id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(url, 'http://', ''), 'https://', ''), 'http://www.', ''), 'https://www.', ''), '/', 1),
    url,
    matches,
    networks
  FROM url_feed
  WHERE status = 'queued'");

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE url_feed
SET    status = 'complete'
WHERE status = 'queued' AND
id IN (SELECT id
FROM   clean_domains)");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My code is working for 99% of domains, but I can't quite figure out how to make it work perfectly.

Here's the 3 times it seems to not work perfectly:

1. Colons - `http://example.com:88/testing` - URLs like this are having their domains output as `example.com:88` whereas I'd want it to be `example.com`.
2. IP Addresses - `http://188.123.44.12/test.php` - For IPs it seems to be correctly entering the IP address into the database.  In the example it would enter `188.123.44.12` as the `domain` - but I don't want that.  I only want domain names, so if it's an IP, it shouldn't be copied over.  It should be marked as `complete` in `url_feed` and move on to the next row.
3. Subdomains - `http://subdomain.whatever.example.com/test.html` - This is being entered into the `domain` column as `subdomain.whatever.example.com` when I want it to be `example.com` instead.

The only way I can think of verifying if a domain being entered is truly a domain would be to run a whois query on each of them.  If it doesn't come back as a valid one, it removed the first block of text.  For example, it wouldn't get a valid result for `subdomain.whatever.example.com` so then it tries `whatever.example.com` and then it tries `example.com` until the result is valid or it skips it and marks the `status` column as `complete`.

Any ideas on what I can change to make this work properly?

**Here's where I am right now with this:**

```
$_url_string = 'https://testfewfew.dsd.google.co.uk/testing/whatever';
preg_match("/[a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6}$/", parse_url($_url_string, PHP_URL_HOST), $_domain_tld);
echo $_domain_tld[0];
```

Comment: i would suggest use regular expression to extract the domain, if not ip insert the record & update url_feed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing Domain From URL In PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php)

Comment: @Shadow my script already does everything listed there.

Comment: the third situation seems to be somehow complicated, as there may be domains like `aaaa.bbbb.example.co.us`. a simple regex won't work this out as it doesn't know whether to take `example.co.us` or `co.us`. you may need the http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db list in your code.

Comment: I would not do this in mysql, but in php, hence I marked it as duplicate with the topic linked sbove. Pls read all answers, not just the top ones! The only thing that is not described there is how to get the domain name from IP. Use gethostbyaddr() function for that.

Comment: @FrederickZhang I was thinking it may be best to just remove the first section, then the section section, and so on until it found the valid domain.  That way it'd work with any domain and a list wouldn't have to be updated every time a new TLD was added.

Comment: @user10848 no, your code only does a fraction of what is discussed in the linked topic. You really need to read the contents, not just the title!

Comment: @Shadow take a look at the code I just posted under "Here's where I am right now with this".  Does that look like it's working to you?  It seems to work with 100% of domains to me.  Almost seems too easy though lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use built-in php function [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

You can filter a subdomain from a hostname like this

```
$url = 'http://subdomain.whatever.example.com/test.html';

$data = parse_url($url);

$host = $data['host'];

$hostname = explode(".", $host);
$domain = $hostname[count($hostname)-2] . "." . $hostname[count($hostname)-1];

print $domain;
```

Will output

```
example.com
```

If you have an `url` with a port, `parse_url` will deal with it easily, example

```
$url = 'http://example.com:88/testing';

$data = parse_url($url);

print_r($data);
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => example.com
    [port] => 88
    [path] => /testing
)
```

And below you check if the hostname is a valid IP address or not

```
$url = 'http://188.123.44.12/test.php';

$data = parse_url($url);

print_r($data);

$hostIsIpAddress = ip2long($data['host']) !== false;

var_dump($hostIsIpAddress);
```

Which will output `bool(true)` or `bool(false)` respectively

Comment: Almost works, I thought of doing similar with `parse_url` but I think we've run into the same issue.  It works with most domains, but not for ones like `.co.uk`.  For example, `http://test.co.uk` become `co.uk`

Comment: You've gotten closer than me with PHP, I just can't think of any way to verify if a domain is actually legit without using whois or a constantly updating list of subtlds.

Comment: see this answer that deals better with multi-level tlds http://stackoverflow.com/a/21809647/5043552

Comment: Can you take a look at the code I just posted under "Here's where I am right now with this".  Does that look like it's working to you?  It seems to work with 100% of domains to me.  Almost seems too easy though lol