# PHP header location based on current path

Tags: php, header

I'm trying to create custom php function for **redirect**. Currently I have this. (I've created index.php file with this function for testing)

```
function redirect($pageName, ...$parameters)
{
    $host  = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_HOST');
    $uri   = rtrim(dirname(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'PHP_SELF')), '/\\');
    foreach ($parameters as $parameter)
        $pageName .= "/".$parameter;
    header("Location: http://{$host}{$uri}/{$pageName}");
}
```

Function works as it should but I have little problem.

I need to make this function work dynamically in **root folder of web**/**subfolder of web**/**subdomain**

*Web is meant as that index.file right now*

- If I have web in **root folder** of website, function works without any problems. *(Function redirect("page") redirects me for example to domain.com/page*
- If I have web in **subfolder of website**, function works again good *(Function redirect("page") redirects me for example to domain.com/folder/page)*
- If I have web in **subdomain**(what is practically subfolder on website) there is problem, for example, I'm on **subdomain.domain.com** . I will use in index.php redirect("page"), the function redirects me to subdomain.domain.com/folderwhereiscontentofsubdomainlocated/page.

I need to make this function working on **all 3 options**, so If user will place website **anywhere**, it will **work** without problems.

I've spent few hours of looking for solution, but I didn't find anything.

Sorry for my little bit bad English, I hope you will understand :)
**Have a nice day**

Comment: Maybe this could help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679618/get-domain-name-not-subdomain-in-php

Comment: Note: As long as you don't validate `HTTP_HOST` and check if it matches your host (domain), it can be changed by the user in anyway he wants. `HTTP_HOST` comes from the HTTP request header `Host`. On my server I always make sure that `HTTP_HOST` matches one domain (and redirect the user if it doesn't match), so I can use it without having to fear that one changed it, as the webserver makes sure it is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for note :)