# Extract domain name from ANY type of url

Tags: javascript, regex, extract

There are many question on SO for extracting the domain name from a variety of URLs, but none of them cover ALL sub-domains and suffixes (.org, .uk, .com, .org.uk, .whatever etc).

**For example:**

http://uselesstext.moretext.DOMAIN.org.uk/

**Result:** DOMAIN.org.uk

The main problem here is that it's seemingly impossible to design an algorithm to identify which part of the URL is the relevant part (without the use of a library) because there can be a varying amount of sub-domains and suffixes.

Any ideas? (In JavaScript preferably)

Comment: Why would `DOMAIN.xyz.com` be the "domain name" here and not either `xyz.com` or `moretext.DOMAIN.xyz.com`?

Comment: well as you stated, you need to have a criteria on what is considered a domain name, and then you build an algorithm based on that, until you have that it is impossible to know what a domain name is

Comment: @duskwuff ok I changed it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9632782/19068

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for here is the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/). It's a list of every domain extension that can have independently administrated domains registered under it (e.g, `com`, `org.uk`, etc).

There are a number of Javascript implementations of this list available. The two most common ones are [publicsuffixlist.js](https://github.com/gorhill/publicsuffixlist.js) and [tld.js](https://github.com/oncletom/tld.js).