# Get root domain from list of subdomains

Tags: google-sheets

I am using google sheets and I am having a list of subdomains:

```
app.example.com
appserver.example.com
bigstone.example.com
cpanel.example.com
cpanel.example3.com
cpanel.example4.com
cpanel.example2.com
cpanel.example2.com
```

I would like to get:

```
example.com
example2.com
example3.com
example4.com
```

Find below my example sheet:

[Google Sheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vCjhF_-C89Fz4bNjV4ggdPKdJGeTiNzBPj49feD7vsg/edit?usp=sharing)

I tried `=left(F2, find(".", F2,2))`, however I only get `.app` etc.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679618/get-domain-name-not-subdomain-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you in cell E2:

=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(IFERROR(MID(A2:A,FIND(".",A2:A)+1,100))))

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right path, but it's better to search from the other side:

`=RIGHT(A1, len(A1) - find(".", A1))`

It basically searches from the right between the length of the cell and the first `.` it finds