# I need a regex that will pull a URL from a text document

Tags: php, regex

The urls I'm trying to pull are all in the format of www.domain.com.  I want to pull them from text documents with a simple regex.  It only needs to match www.domain.com, and not other url variations.

What is the simplest regex to use with preg_match_all()?

Comment: Check out this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399250/going-where-php-parse-url-doesnt-parsing-only-the-domain/399316#399316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/w{3}\.\w{2,}\.\w{3}/
```

this will match `www.` any word with more than two letters `dot` + 3 letters

to match domains with hyphen or uppercase letters:

```
/w{3}\.[\w\-]{2,}\.\w{3}/i
```

Comment: This regex would not find something like www.do-main.com

Comment: It would probably help if it found this format as well... although this does satisfy my original request.

Answer (score 1):

I don't do a whole lot with PHP, but the regex would be something like:

```
w{3}.([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?
```

will return all domain names that start with "www.". It will ignore the protocol part of the tag (e.g. `http://`)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('%((mailto\\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\\://){1}\\S+)%m', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    // $result[0][$i];
}
```

You can also use a class that I wrote, https://github.com/homer6/altumo/blob/master/source/php/String/Url.php if you want to easily pull parts of the url. See the unit test in the same directory for usage.

If you're looking for a good program to tweak your regex patterns, I highly recommend [regexbuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/).

Hope that helps...