# Get the parent document.domain without subdomains

Tags: javascript

Say that I have a domain `subdomain.domain.com`, when I check the `document.domain` I'm getting the result `subdomain.domain.com`, what can I do to get only the original domain without the sub domain, for example: `domain.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for a `.com` domain in the example you specified, you would have to adjust the slice for `.co.uk`, `.com.au` and some other TLDs:

```
document.domain.split(".").slice(-2).join(".");
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what will be the domain, I need something more generic.

Comment: @UdiTalias: can you guarantee that it will only be `subdomain.domain.tld` or can it be `subdomain.subdomain.domain.tld`?

Comment: It can be also subdomain.subdomain.domain.tld. Actually I don't know what will be the domain, it can be anything...

Comment: @Udi: then you're going to struggle because the only way to do it is to have an up-to-date list of all TLDs (keeping note of which have CCSLDs), and continuing to maintain it as new ones are introduced.

Comment: @Udi: see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399250/going-where-php-parse-url-doesnt-parsing-only-the-domain) looking for a similar solution in PHP for more information.

Comment: Posting this for [Yanislav Tankov](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6640908/yanislav-tankov): `document.domain.split(".").slice(-2).join(".");` works for me for all domains .com, .co.uk, sub.domain.co.uk domain.co... etc. BUT not for male.domain.co.uk