# How to get the home page URL link

Tags: java, python, url

Let's say I am on the webpage
`https://company.slack.com/messages/@user1/`

How could I get the URL of home page of the company/website in Java/Python which is `https://slack.com/`
(in this case)

Now this seems so easy for some cases, but I want to generalise this & unable to cover all cases like that of slack/google_design/etc....

Say similar cases are:

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deL9VeNjcH8`

Expected Output: `https://www.youtube.com`

`https://angel.co/weav-music?utm_source=lb`

Expected Output: `https://angel.co`

`https://design.google.com/`

Expected Output: `https://www.google.com`

The code from the link below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "https://angel.co/weav-music?utm_source=lb";
    int cnt=0;
    int p;
    int l=s.length();
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            if(s[i]=='/' && cnt!=3)
                cnt++;
            if(s[i]=='/' && cnt==3){
                p=i;break;}
        }
    cout<<s.substr(0,p);
    return 0;
}
```

@all
**Please see JonasCz's 2nd comment on his own answer that actually helped 
me**

Comment: I had successfully implemented examples of Youtube, angel.co by simple detecting first '/' in the URL after http://

Comment: We'd like to see your code.

Comment: Sure, will post in sometime

Comment: There's no perfect way to generate the "home page" for a domain in a URL.  I could choose any arbitrary subdomain as my "home page" over the conventions of "www.mycompany.com" or "mycompany.com".  Your best bet is probably what is being suggested by JonasCz below.  As an example, say the URL is "http://support.arbitrarydomain.org/users/14".  What is your expected output from that?

Comment: @Marc: My expected output is "arbitrarydomain.org"

Comment: @KlausD. http://ideone.com/DGJRt2 Now if you can suggest some thing?

Comment: @KlausD. Please don't do unncessary stuff on my code, if you have something important to guide me, I will be thankful to me, Don't do rubbish things in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
URL aURL = new URL("https://company.slack.com/messages/@user1/");
System.out.println(aURL.getProtocol() + "://" + aURL.getHost());
```

Which prints:

```
https://company.slack.com
```

This works for other URLs too. See [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html) for more details.

---

If you want to get only the main domain, without the subdomain (i.e. only `http://slack.com`), you can [use Guava's InternetDomainName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199862/get-domain-without-subdomain-from-a-url), eg. like this:

```
InternetDomainName.from("company.slack.com").topPrivateDomain().name();
```

The above will return `slack.com`.

The above method call will work for older Guava library versions. For Guava 19.0 use **toString()** instead of **.name()**

---

To be complete, the whole code, in your case, would look like this:

```
URL aURL = new URL("https://company.slack.com/messages/@user1/");
InternetDomainName.from(aURL.getHost()).topPrivateDomain().name();
```

Comment: and also split the result by dots and replace subdomain with nothing if exists.

Comment: No, but I want output to be slack.com not company.slack.com

Comment: company in company.slack.com is like a user in the domain

Comment: @Prashant But for youtube you want to have **www**.youtube.com ? How do you decide whether to keep or remove the subdomain (first) part for each URL ? I guess you could use a regex..

Comment: @JonasCz: I always want to get the home page URL of the company/product. So in Youtube as well home page is YouTube.com
and I would not want the video ID

Comment: @Prashant Have a look at this: [Get domain without subdomain from a URL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3199862). You'll need Guava libarary. Or use a regex. Check this also, it may work for you: [Extract main domain name from a given url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34466483)

Comment: Okay, Let me check

Comment: @JonasCz: Thanks, it seems to work in most  of the cases, thanks again

Comment: @JonasCz: Please include both the links of your comment, that actually helped in your answer.

Comment: @JonasCz: I am getting Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid domain name: 'https://design.google.com/resources/'
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:115)
 at com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName.<init>(InternetDomainName.java:154)
 at com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName.from(InternetDomainName.java:225)
 at jython.Java_python.main(Java_python.java:10)
This error for URL https://design.google.com/resources/
Why?

Comment: @JonasCz: Any idea?

Comment: The problem is that you need to give `InternetDomainName.from` only the domain, ie. `design.google.com`, _not_ `design.google.com/resources/`. You should be using something like this: `URL aURL = new URL("https://company.slack.com/messages/@user1/");
InternetDomainName.from(aURL.getHost()).topPrivateDomain().name();` @Prashant , what does your code look like ?

Comment: Ohh my bad, you told yesterday only. Thanks

Comment: @JonasCz: topPrivateDomain().name(); In this method call .name() is unrecognised for Guava 19.0 while it was working fine for 16.0 I tried checking alternative for .name() in new version here https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release19 but didn't find anything significiant, any other resource where i could find this?

Comment: this also has no info http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html#topPrivateDomain()