# Getting domain without subdomain from an url with javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get a domain without any subdomain from an url with javascript? I tried some approaches, but all of them deliver domain with subdomain.

All regular expressions i was seeing were able just to filter `www` out - other subdomains were on their place.

Maybe somebody knows a javascript hint, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24409988/1992004) in Java.

Possible input: `https://us.www.example.com/folder-1/index.html`

Desired output: `example.com`

To go more in detail: i'm working on a Chrome extension and want to pass a domain from background.js to popup.js. I get current url, and then the domain from the current url with:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, changeInfo, tab){
    chrome.tabs.query({'active' : true, 'currentWindow': true}, function(tabs){
        let newUrl = new URL(tabs[0].url);
        currentDomain = newUrl.hostname;
});
```

But - trouble - `currentDomain` comes with subdomain.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include an example input and desired output, as well as some code that you've tried?

Comment: sure, you was just faster then me:)

Comment: Can you show your research effort? What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: `new URL("https://us.www.example.com/folder-1/index.html").host` gives you the host.  Just remove the subdomain.

Comment: @CanO'Spam yep - updated

Comment: @Amy `host` works exactly as `hostname` for me - from `https://www.example.com/folder/file.html` it delivers `www.example.com`

Comment: @R3tep yes, this will be enough. Thank you!

Comment: @Evgeniy Of course it does.  Did you not read the last sentence of my comment?