# list of 2ld.1ld (2nd level domain.1st(top)level domain) names?

Tags: list, dns, dummy-data

I am looking for a list of (doesnt matter if its not all, just needs to be big as its for generating dummy data)

Im looking for a list like

```
.net.nz
.co.nz
.edu.nz
.govt.nz
.com.au
.govt.au
.com
.net
```

any ideas where I can locate a list?

Comment: I have found http://publicsuffix.org/ but have no idea how I would format that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288810/get-the-subdomain-from-a-url). Most of them are relating to the use of http://publicsuffix.org/, and even some implementations to use it were given in some languages, like Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

To get all the ICANN domains, this python code should work for you:

```py
import requests
url = 'https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat'
page = requests.get(url)

icann_domains = []
for line in page.text.splitlines():
    if 'END ICANN DOMAINS' in line:
        break
    elif line.startswith('//'):
        continue
    else:
        domain = line.strip()
        if domain:
            icann_domains.append(domain)

print(len(icann_domains)) # 7334 as of Nov 2018
```

Remove the `break` statement to get private domains as well.

Be careful as you will get some domains like this: `*.kh` (e.g. `http://www.mptc.gov.kh/dns_registration.htm`). The `*` is a wildcard.