# preg_match_all regex subdomains

Tags: regex, preg-match-all, subdomain

Hi I have this regex to match ursl, but i need to match subdomains too.

```
public function getUrls($url){
     preg_match_all( "#(www\.|https?:\/\/){1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}(\S*)#i",$url, $matches );
     return $matches[0];
}
```

this match http://domain.com but not http://sub.domain.com

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Take a look to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288810/get-the-subdomain-from-a-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\.` with `([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\.)+`. But the regex matches a lot of invalid domains, and probably won't match all valid urls either. It would be wiser to use a proper parser library for urls if the language you're using provides it.