# Get domain (without TLD) using PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the subdomain from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288810/get-the-subdomain-from-a-url)

I have seen posts about using parse_url to get www.domain.tld but how can i just get "domain" using php?

i have got this regex currently

```
$pattern = '@https?://[a-z]{1,}\.{0,}([a-z]{1,})\.com(\.[a-z]{1,}){0,}@';
```

but this only works with .com and i need it to work with all TLDs (.co.uk, .com , .tv etc.)

Is there a reliable way to do this, i am not sure if regex is the best way to go or not? or maybe explode on "." but then again subdomains would mess it up.

**EDIT**

so the desired outcome would be

```
$url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952907/get-domain-without-tld-using-php#comment15926320_11952907";

$output = "stackoverflow";
```

Doing more research would anyone advise using parse_url to get www.domain.tld then using explode to get domain?

Comment: You need a list of all publicly available suffixes.  (to distinguish between `.co.uk` and `.co.mil`)

Comment: you need to check if domain is valid or only domain name ?

Comment: So i'd need to write down all of these into a array? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Comment: @MihaiIorga All i need is the domain from the url.

Comment: @user1527354: No. http://publicsuffix.org/

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex :

```
#^https?://(www\.)?([^/]*?)(\.co)?\.[^.]+?/#
```

Comment: There is a problem when it is used with .co.uk domains.
Array ( [0] => http://stackoverflow.co.uk/ [1] => [2] => stackoverflow.co )

Comment: http://publicsuffix.org/

Comment: You also have country code domains `com.br`, other second level domains ex `.ac.uk`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `parse_url` function. Doc is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Something like:

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
print_r(parse_url($url));
```

And then you can take `$url['host']` and do:

```
$arr = explode('.',$url['host']);
return $arr[count($arr) - 2];
```

Comment: Try using it with a valid url and you see it is not the desired outcome.
Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => www.google.com [path] => /efaafafaf.php [query] => id=78abak )

Comment: Yes, you can if you get the `[host]` and `explode()` it and take the 2nd element from the tail.

Comment: Breaks for .co.uk or .org.br or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need regex.

```
function getDomain($url){
    $things_like_WWW_at_the_start = array('www');
    $urlContents = parse_url($url);
    $domain = explode('.', $urlContents['host']);

    if (!in_array($domain[0], $things_like_WWW_at_the_start))
        return $domain[0];
    else
        return $domain[1];
}
```

Comment: This will retrieve the complete hostname, ex `www.google.com`. The OP wants to get the TLD only (`google` in this example)

Comment: This seems good, what other things would you suggest i put in the array to make it defiantly work cross urls?

Comment: @user1527354 Since many websites use subdomains to handle locale versions, I would add common language codes: `en`, `fr`, `de`, ...

Comment: @user1527354 But if you have urls like stackexchange sites things will get really bad with this function. I mean you have to list everything in that array.