# SQL functions to match last two parts of a URL

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, postgresql-8.3

This is a follow up question to a post here [Regex for matching last two parts of a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313965/regex-for-matching-last-two-parts-of-a-url)

I was wondering if I could use built in sql funcitons to accomplish the same type of pattern match without using regular expressions.  In particular I was thinking if there was a way to reverse the string say www.stackoverflow.com to com.stackoverflow.www and then apply concatenation to split('com.stackoverflow.www , '.', 1) || split('com.stackoverflow.www , '.', 2) I would be done but I am not sure if this is possible.

Here is the general problem description:

I am trying to figure out the best sql function simply match only the last two strings seperated by a . in a url.

For instance with www.stackoverflow.com I just want to match stackoverflow.com

The issue i have is some strings can have a large number of periods for instance

a-abcnewsplus.i-a277eea3.rtmp.atlas.cdn.yimg.com

should also return only yimg.com

The set of URLS I am working with does not have any of the path information so one can assume the last part of the string is always .org or .com or something of that nature.

> What sql functions will return stackoverflow.com when run against www.stackoverflow.com and will return yimg.com when run against a-abcnewsplus.i-a277eea3.rtmp.atlas.cdn.yimg.com under the conditions stated above?  I did not want to use regular expressions in the solution just sql string manipulation functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

doesn't look like you can do it with 8.3 function set http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-string.html

there's no reverse - that comes in 9.1. with that you could do:

```
select reverse(split_part(reverse(data), '.', 2)) || '.'
    || reverse(split_part(reverse(data), '.', 1))
from example;
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/25e43/2/0

you can declare your own reverse: http://a-kretschmer.de/diverses.shtml and then solve this problem.

but regex is just easier...

Comment: `substring(data, '[^.]+\.[^.]+$')` is about 50% slower than your solution in my tests. You can slightly simplify to: `reverse((split_part(reverse(data), '.', 1)) || '.' || (split_part(reverse(data), '.', 2)))`