# How to check Referrer url is Domain OR Sub domain in PHP script

Tags: php, regex

I want to check the Referrer url is Main Domain or Sub domain, domain can be anything like .com , .net ,.co.in , in .. Sub Domain also can be different type… any one can suggest idea in PHP script …..

For e.g if referrer url is http://google.com is the Domain, http://in.google.net is the sub domain

Comment: Do you want to check against a list of domains (e.g. something like `if ( referrer_is('*.google.*') { ... }`) or extract a string from the domain (e.g. `echo get_referrer_domain_string()` giving you `google'`)?

Comment: No.. I want to indentify request is from domain Or subDomain ?

Comment: Perhaps you could give some examples of input and the output you want for each?

Comment: Guss the Referrer Url is **www.abc.com** so its a domain write ? and if the Referrer url is **www.mysubdomian.abc.com** its call sub domain .. write ? i want to identify the domain type, means Domain or sub domain.....

Comment: Sub-domain is a relative term: technically, `.com` is a "top-level domain", "example.com" is "a sub-domain of .com", and "www.example.com" is a "a sub-domain of example.com". So "co.uk" is a sub-domain of ".uk", but in practical terms is considered a "public suffix" because different people own the different sub-domains under it. This is a tricky rule to codify; one notable attempt is [the Mozilla Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/).

Comment: The Public Suffix List site led me back to StackOverflow. You might want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288810/get-the-subdomain-from-a-url

Comment: IMSoP, Thanks For Reply, But i want PHP Script that can identify Url is Subdomain or Domain ?

Comment: Then you will need to work out exactly what you want "sub-domain" to mean...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. (Haven't tested the code - so please take as a suggestion only)

```
<?php
$fromOtherDomain = !preg_match('/^https?:\/\/' . preg_quote($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . '/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']);
?>
```

Comment: Bas Kuis , Thanks for the answer.. But i want to track the referrer url is Domain Or Sub Domain... the referrer url can be any from the world...

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer.
The requirement has changed and I now match all subdomains belonging to same domain (*.example.com).
So I have used the following code:

```php
if(!preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9].example.com/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    echo 'Sub Domain';
}else{
    echo 'Main domain OR sub domain not belongs to example.com'
}
```