# How do I parse a URL in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing Domain From URL In PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php)

how do i get

```
http://localhost/
```

from

```
http://localhost/something/
```

using php

I tried

```
    $base  = strtok($url, '/');
```

Comment: which of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+url+php have you tried and why didnt they solve your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) to get down to the hostname.

e.g.:

```
$url = "http://localhost/path/to/?here=there";
$data = parse_url($url);
var_dump($data);

/*
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => localhost
    [path] => /path/to/
    [query] => here=there
)
*/
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$url = 'http://localhost/something/';
$parsedurl  = parse_url($url);
echo $parsedurl['scheme'].'://'.$parsedurl['host'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out `parse_url()` - http://php.net/parse_url