# Find to extract portion of a string in PHP

Tags: php, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do i parse url php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624370/how-do-i-parse-url-php)

I have strings in the format of 'http://www.example.com/', some of them have the trailing slash, and other don't, how would I extract 'example.com' from them?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).  You want the `host` component.  Once you have that, you can remove the `www.` if it exists.