# PHP parse_url check path

Tags: php

I am trying to check if a current path is being used, for example:

www.mydomain.com/abc/123/content

How do I go about checking whether the current path is abc i.e. the check should succeed for all abc e.g. abc/123/content as well as abc/456/content but fail otherwise e.g. for bcd/123/content

thanks

Comment: "Is being used", do you mean exists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i parse url php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624370/how-do-i-parse-url-php)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598480/php-parse-current-url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624370/how-do-i-parse-url-php and probably fifty other duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Get the current url with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and than look if the string contains 'abs' with the [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function. Like:

```
<?php
    if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'abc') !== false)
        //found
?>
```

Comment: actually, strpos( 'abc/foo', 'abc' ) would return 0 (as the substring starts at position 0. Append a !== false, and you're right ;)

Comment: I would also use stripos() instead of strpos() because it's case-insensitive so 'ABC/FOO' will still work.