# regex URL cut question mark

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing Domain From URL In PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php)
>   [How do I parse a URL in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624370/how-do-i-parse-a-url-in-php)

I have this code:

```
$url = preg_replace("/^(http:\/\/)*(www.)*/is", "", $url);
    $url = preg_replace("/\/.*$/is" , "" ,$url);
```

It work good get domain name where after .com is / . I got problem if there is url like this:

```
http://www.something.com?id=21213
```

What do I need to add to regex to cut ?id=21213 so there remains only something.com

Comment: What exactly do you require? Given a url www.something.com/?id=123 which part of it do you want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i parse url php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624370/how-do-i-parse-url-php); [Parsing Domain from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php)

Comment: -1: Didn't bother to look in the manual.

Comment: GarethL - cut ?id=21213 so there remains only something.com hakre- parse_url() is not option.

Answer (score 2):

See the magical build in function of [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Using `parse_url()`, you can retrieve the domain name solely by:

```
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
if(0 === strpos('www.', $domain)){
    $domain = substr($domain, 4);
}
```

Comment: If I use this there is still www part. I need only domain.com.

Comment: updated code to remove `www.`