# Getting the domain name of a remote website page in PHP?

Tags: php, dns, fetch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing Domain From URL In PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php)

Basically I have a form where a user puts in a url of a page to save (e.g. http://domain.com/random/page) and I want it to just get the domain name of the website (domain.com). How do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look the function [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), and get the "host" key from the array.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the `http://` and then split the string by `/`.  Take the first value of the resulting array from the split.