# Extract registered domain from URL based on Public Suffix List

Tags: php, url, domain-name

Given a URL, how do I extract the registered domain using the [Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/list/) (list of effective TLDs, e.g. [this list](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1))?

For instance, considering `a.bg` is a valid public suffix:

```
http://www.test.start.a.bg/hello.html -> start.a.bg 
http://test.start.a.bg/               -> start.a.bg
http://test.start.abc.bg/             -> abc.bg (.bg is the public suffix)
```

This cannot be done using simple string manipulation because the public suffix can consist of multiple levels depending on the TLD.

P.S. It doesn't matter how I read the list (database or flat file), but the list should be accessible locally so I'm not always dependent on external services.

Comment: how about make use on services/api provided by whois? an example, http://whoisxmlapi.com/

Comment: Compare to what? What's the "right output"? Your question is incredibly unclear.

Comment: @ajreal, I don't want to be dependent.

Comment: @Chris I don't even see a question here!

Comment: This is likely to be a rehash of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8263758/115845

Comment: @ilhan I've rewritten your question based on what I could gather from this and your last [few](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8272216/115845) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8263758/115845) (and [the one on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113624/134327)). Feel free to update if you feel I've misquoted your requirements.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `parse_url()` to extract the hostname, then use the [library provided by regdom](http://www.dkim-reputation.org/regdom-lib-downloads/) to determine the registered domain name (dn + eTLD). For example:

```
require_once("effectiveTLDs.inc.php");
require_once("regDomain.inc.php");

$url =  'http://www.metu.edu.tr/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html';
echo getRegisteredDomain(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
```

That will print out `metu.edu.tr`.

Other examples I've tried:

```
http://www.xyz.start.bg/hello   ->   start.bg
http://www.start.a.bg/world     ->   start.a.bg  (a.bg is a listed eTLD)
http://xyz.ma219.metu.edu.tr    ->   metu.edu.tr
http://www.google.com/search    ->   google.com
http://google.co.uk/search?asd  ->   google.co.uk
```

UPDATE: These libraries have been moved to: https://github.com/leth/registered-domains-php

Comment: Given that this seems to be the right answer (well done) do you think you could clarify the question, resulting in a clear question/answer pair? There seems to be quite some confusion in this and previous questions of the OP.

Comment: @Shawn Chin, thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. I've only added "php" after "<?" and changed this line "$signingDomainParts = split('\.', $signingDomain);" to "$signingDomainParts = explode('.', $signingDomain);"

Comment: @Bart done. Feel free to improve if it needs more clarification.

Comment: Excellent. I would say now the question is clear and useful for others.

Comment: Something like this would be very useful as a jQuery plugin - it's an important bit of validation.

Comment: @donkapone It is indeed an important bit of validation. However, AFAIK this is usually done on the server side and seldom on the client end so I'm not sure how useful such a plugin would be. Of course, I may be mistaken (as usual).

Comment: Note that this doesn't appear to work with co.uk :-(

Comment: @K2xL it should, as shown in one of the examples above. What domain name did you try with?

Comment: @ShawnChin google.co.uk, gives me co.uk as the domain :-\. Ended up using a different library

Comment: @K2xL what library you using? Btw, yes, org.uk, and co.uk doesn't provide desirable output.

Answer (score 5):

This question is a bit old, but there's a new solution: https://github.com/jeremykendall/php-domain-parser

This library does exactly what you want. Here's the setup:

```
$pslManager = new Pdp\PublicSuffixListManager();
$parser = new Pdp\Parser($pslManager->getList());
echo $parser->getRegisterableDomain('www.scottwills.co.uk');
```

This will print `"scottwills.co.uk"`.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend to use [TLDExtract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract), it has regurly updatable database that generated from [PSL](https://publicsuffix.org/).

```
$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();

$result = $extract->parse('shop.github.com');
$result->getFullHost(); // will return (string) 'shop.github.com'
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return (string) 'github.com'
$result->isValidDomain(); // will return (bool) true
$result->isIp(); // will return (bool) false
```