# How to check if a variable contains a valid url using PHP and jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dns, whois

I'm trying to make a whois check script.

User can submit some domain address and then get a message if it's available or not.

`$_POST['url']` is the submitted value by user.

How do I know if this variable is a domain name address?

It should give `true` for domains like:

```
http://google.com
www.google.com
http://www.google.com
google.com
```

**Same for javascript (I'm using ajax-validation also)?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Domain From URL In PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php)

Comment: @Jon This is about validation, not extraction.

Comment: @Madmartigan I think we shouldn't send any queries since valid url is submitted

Comment: @Madmartigan True, but http://coca.cola isn't a valid URL (yet).

Comment: Anyone knows some similar script to check domain address by javascript or jQuery?

Comment: @Steve http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/452

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment too soon. For clarity to anyone else reading, it was "Doesn't the Whois check do the URL validation?".

Comment: whois check is done on a third-party resource. I'm using jQuery to validate the url, if its true, send value to php, which checks the domain, then get value back from ajax and show the message to the user.

Comment: @Steve Maybe this will help you validate the url in jQuery: http://www.robsearles.com/2010/05/27/jquery-validate-url-adding-http/

Comment: You really should make the distinction between "valid url" and "valid domain name", they are two completely different things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to check if the url is a valid url you could use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with the [`FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) filter.

```
filter_var($_POST['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)
```

Comment: @Steve Easy fix, simply prepend http:// if there is none, then use this function.

Comment: @Madmartigan ok, do you know some solution for javascript check?

Comment: @Steve I'm sorry I missed your example urls. I thought that you wanted to check if the url was valid. An url without protocol is not an valid url.

Comment: @Steve: IMO, either enforce a strict URL format, either by validation or formatting the string yourself, then just pass it over to the Whois API. The thing is, you are trying to accept and validate strings that simply are not valid URLs by themselves, like `this.one`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

**Example:**

```
$url = "http://0gate.com"; // you can use instead - $_POST['url']
if (!preg_match("/^[http|https]*[:\/\/]*[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.([A-Za-z]{3,4})+([\.A-Za-z]{3})*$/i", $url)) {
  echo "The domain [not valid - false]";
}else{
  echo "The domain is [valid - true]";
}
```

Comment: Oh you mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/276525/398242)? If you are going to copy/paste answers, at least attribute your source.

Comment: If you only need the host you can use `$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);`

Comment: @LionKing: No offense, it was just blatantly obvious that you copied the linked answer and changed a few characters.

Comment: @Lion King Helping correctly when a question is already answered would be linking to the question in a comment and/or flagging this question.

Comment: what, if its not a domain, how do we know? false on $getdomain?

Comment: @Steve: The value will be NULL. Quoting the [docs](http://us.php.net/parse_url): `If the requested component doesn't exist within the given URL, NULL will be returned.`

Comment: Do not use this regex, it is wrong on so many levels. You do not know about ccTLDs for example?