# How to remove http://, www and slash from URL in PHP?

Tags: php, url

I need a php function which produce a pure domain name from URL. So this function must be remove `http://`, `www` and `/`(slash) parts from URL if these parts exists. Here is example input and outputs:
Input - > http://www.google.com/ | Output -> google.com 
Input - > http://google.com/ | Output -> google.com 
Input - > www.google.com/ | Output -> google.com 
Input - > google.com/ | Output -> google.com 
Input - > google.com | Output -> google.com 
I checked `parse_url` function, but doesn't return what I need.
Since, I'm beginner in PHP, it was difficult for me. If you have any idea, please answer.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: parse_url will keep the full domain name, including subdomains, e.g. it doesnt turn www.google.com into just google.com

Comment: The second top rated answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php) is probably the simplest bet.

Comment: @Ben doesnt work for secure.google.com and similar

Comment: Ah true, never thought of that

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
$input = 'www.google.co.uk/';

// in case scheme relative URI is passed, e.g., //www.google.com/
$input = trim($input, '/');

// If scheme not included, prepend it
if (!preg_match('#^http(s)?://#', $input)) {
    $input = 'http://' . $input;
}

$urlParts = parse_url($input);

// remove www
$domain = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $urlParts['host']);

echo $domain;

// output: google.co.uk
```

Works correctly with all your example inputs.

Comment: @Gordon: Question stated `must be remove http://, www and /`. Arbitrary subdomains were not part of it and wouldn't work anyways if he needed it to.

Answer (score 33):

```
$str = 'http://www.google.com/';
$str = preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', rtrim($str,'/'));
echo $str; // www.google.com
```

Answer (score 10):

There are lots of ways grab the domain out of a url I've posted 4 ways below starting from the shortest to the longest.

**#1**

```
function urlToDomain($url) {
   return implode(array_slice(explode('/', preg_replace('/https?:\/\/(www\.)?/', '', $url)), 0, 1));
}
echo urlToDomain('http://www.example.com/directory/index.php?query=true');
```

**#2**

```
function urlToDomain($url) {
   $domain = explode('/', preg_replace('/https?:\/\/(www\.)?/', '', $url));
   return $domain['0'];
}
echo urlToDomain('http://www.example.com/directory/index.php?query=true');
```

**#3**

```
function urlToDomain($url) {
   $domain = preg_replace('/https?:\/\/(www\.)?/', '', $url);
   if ( strpos($domain, '/') !== false ) {
      $explode = explode('/', $domain);
      $domain  = $explode['0'];
   }
   return $domain;
}
echo urlToDomain('http://www.example.com/directory/index.php?query=true');
```

**#4**

```
function urlToDomain($url) {
   if ( substr($url, 0, 8) == 'https://' ) {
      $url = substr($url, 8);
   }
   if ( substr($url, 0, 7) == 'http://' ) {
      $url = substr($url, 7);
   }
   if ( substr($url, 0, 4) == 'www.' ) {
      $url = substr($url, 4);
   }
   if ( strpos($url, '/') !== false ) {
      $explode = explode('/', $url);
      $url     = $explode['0'];
   }
   return $url;
}
echo urlToDomain('http://www.example.com/directory/index.php?query=true');
```

All of the functions above return the same response: `example.com`

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it will remove what you wanted (http:://, www and trailing slash) but will retain other subdomains such as example.google.com

```
$host = parse_url('http://www.google.com', PHP_URL_HOST);
$host = preg_replace('/^(www\.)/i', '', $host);
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
$host = preg_replace('/^(www\.)/i', '', parse_url('http://www.google.com', PHP_URL_HOST));
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked to have http://, www and trailing slashed removed therefore my solution only removes these. Other solutions could be a lot trickier and would probably need a database of exceptions, .uk, .tw domains would for example cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!preg_match('/^http(s)?:\/\//', $url))
    $url = 'http://' . $url;

$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$host = explode('.', strrev($host));
$host = strrev($host[1]) . '.' strrev($host[0]);
```

This would return second level domain, though it would be useless for say .co.uk domains, so you might want to do some more checking, and include additional parts if strrev($host[0]) is uk, au, etc.

Answer (score 2):

First way is to use one regular expression to trim unnecesary parts of URL like protocol, www and ending slash

```
function trimUrlProtocol($url) {
    return preg_replace('/((^https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?)|(\/$)/', '', trim($url));
}

echo trimUrlProtocol('http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/') . PHP_EOL;
echo trimUrlProtocol('https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/') . PHP_EOL;
echo trimUrlProtocol('http://www.sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/') . PHP_EOL;
echo trimUrlProtocol('https://www.sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/') . PHP_EOL;
echo trimUrlProtocol('http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com') . PHP_EOL;
echo trimUrlProtocol('https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com') . PHP_EOL;
echo trimUrlProtocol('http://www.sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com') . PHP_EOL;
echo trimUrlProtocol('https://www.sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com') . PHP_EOL;
echo trimUrlProtocol('sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com') . PHP_EOL;
```

By alternative way you can use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), but you have to make additional cheks to check if `host` part exists and then use regular expression to trim `www`. Just use first way, it is simple and lazy.

Comment: this also works in case the "www" is not in the parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
$value = 'https://google.ca';
$result = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($value, PHP_URL_HOST));
// google.ca
```

Comment: will not work if url is simply 'www.google.com' - sadface.

Answer (score 1):

This will account for "http/https", "www" and the ending slash

```
$str = 'https://www.google.com/';
$str = preg_replace('#(^https?:\/\/(w{3}\.)?)|(\/$)#', '', $str);
echo $str; // google.com
```

Just ask if you need help understanding the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use parse_url

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: OP specifically said parse_url doesnt return what he needs, e.g. it keeps the domain name including subdomains

Comment: parse_url also doesn't care about www.