# Mysql query to check if url exists in database

Tags: php, mysql

lets say I have $_POST['url']='http://myexamplesite.com/images/image.jpg';
how can I get correct result if this url exists in the database but looks like:
http://www.myexamplesite.com/images/image.jpg

if I do:

```
$q='select id from products where url LIKE "%'.$_POST['url'].'%"';
```

This will not return always correct results. What is the correct way?
Thanks

Comment: probably you are looking for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364242/how-to-remove-http-www-and-slash-from-url-in-php

Comment: It is clear how to compare both in php, but how to do this in mysql query?

Comment: So you need a solution only within MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need pure SQL solution, you can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` for that:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'http://', -1), 'www.',-1) = 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('".$_POST['url']."', 'http://', -1), 'www.',-1)
```

This will remove `http://` and `www.` from both strings and will compare the rest.

Comment: Well done man, this does exactly what is suppose to do, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Either

1) Standardise the URLs within the database if they are all on your own site

or

2) [Remove the http://, http://, and www. from search URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18560043/128161) like so:

```
function pure_url($url) {
   if ( substr($url, 0, 7) == 'http://' ) {
      $url = substr($url, 7);
   }
   if ( substr($url, 0, 8) == 'https://' ) {
      $url = substr($url, 8);
   }
   if ( substr($url, 0, 6) == 'ftp://') {
      $url = substr($url, 6);
   }
   if ( substr($url, 0, 4) == 'www.') {
      $url = substr($url, 4);
   }
   return $url;
}

$url = pure_url('http://www.myexamplesite.com/images/image.jpg');
// $url = 'myexamplesite.com/images/image.jpg';
```

Comment: What about `ftp` protocol ?

Comment: if ( substr($url, 0, 4) == 'ftp.') {
      $url = substr($url, 4);
   }

Comment: Jamie, thanks, but this aint solve the problem because first url-s are for different sites each time and second $_POST may look 'http://www.myexamplesite.com/images/image.jpg' but in database to be 'http://myexamplesite.com/images/image.jpg' and opposite

Comment: @Europeuser You would apply the function to the posted URL, which removes the protocols then when you search the database it will return both cases.

Comment: @Europeuser Correct, and your SQL using the `%` wildcard  at the start and end of the search string, so both cases will be returned.