# How can I use PHP to get just the base name from a long url?

Tags: php, regex

If I have a variable that contains a URL, then how can I get the base URL? That is,

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/some/stuff/that/I/do/not/want/';
$base_url = some_clever_function($url);
// $base_url is now set equal to 'domain.com'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Domain From URL In PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) will be able to extract the host for you.

It has the second argument with the help of which you can extract different parts of URL. To extract host, use `parse_url` the following way:

```
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$url = 'http://google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html';
$parse = parse_url($url);
print $parse['host']; // prints 'google.com'
```

Second method

```
<?php
// get host name from URL
preg_match("/^(http:\/\/)?([^\/]+)/i",
    "http://www.php.net/index.html", $matches);
$host = $matches[2];

// get last two segments of host name
preg_match("/[^\.\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/", $host, $matches);
echo "domain name is: {$matches[0]}\n";

/* Output is php.net */


?>
```

Comment: If you're going to blatantly copy code, you should at least give credit to [the original authors (Ex. #3)](http://php.net/preg_match).

Comment: https? and second example again is missing optional protocol