# Get domain name from full URL

Tags: php, url

say someone enters a URL like this:

```
http://i.imgur.com/a/b/c?query=value&query2=value
```

And I want to return: `imgur.com`

not `i.imgur.com`

This is code I have right now

```
$sourceUrl = parse_url($url);
$sourceUrl = $sourceUrl['host'];
```

But this returns `i.imgur.com`

Comment: how about the one that starts "Here's a method to get the REAL name of a domain."

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288810/get-the-subdomain-from-a-url

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php

Comment: https://gist.github.com/praisedpk/64bdb80d28144aa78d58469324432277

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Check the code below, it should do the job fine.

```
<?php

function get_domain($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : $pieces['path'];
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}

print get_domain("http://mail.somedomain.co.uk"); // outputs 'somedomain.co.uk'

?>
```

Comment: This is a *little* tricky. It'll end up returning incorrect results for subdomains of first-level ccTLDs, like `blah.blah.de`. But there's no way around that without using the Public Suffix List.

Comment: This will not work for `www.domain.com` - parse_url() need a protocol (http://) to define a host, otherwise it's just path. Needs a secondary conditional under the first: `$domain = ( empty( $domain ) && isset( $pieces['path'] ) ) ? $pieces['path'] : $domain;`

Comment: @stanev01 this is not working for https://successonline.services/why-you-should-stay-in-college-even-if-youre-a-future-ceo/

Comment: @BharatDangar Use `'/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,10})$/i'` as the first argument to `preg_replace()` to allow up to 10 chars in the TLD.

Answer (score 8):

You need package that using [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/). Yes, you can use string functions arround parse_url() or regex, but they will produce incorrect result in complex URLs.

I recomend [TLDExtract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract) for domain parsing, here is sample code:

```
$url = 'http://i.imgur.com/a/b/c?query=value&query2=value';

parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST); // will return 'i.imgur.com'

$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();
$result = $extract->parse($url);
$result->getFullHost(); // will return 'i.imgur.com'
$result->getSubdomain(); // will return 'i'
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return 'imgur.com'
$result->getSuffix(); // will return 'com'
```

Comment: it is depreciated, pleae use https://github.com/jeremykendall/php-domain-parser

Answer (score 4):

I have found a very useful library using publicsuffix.org, 
**[PHP Domain Parser](https://github.com/jeremykendall/php-domain-parser)** is a Public Suffix List based domain parser implemented in PHP.

https://github.com/jeremykendall/php-domain-parser

```
 <?php 
 // this will do the job

 require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

 $pslManager = new Pdp\PublicSuffixListManager();
 $parser = new Pdp\Parser($pslManager->getList());
 var_dump($parser->getRegistrableDomain('www.scottwills.co.uk'));
 ?>
```

> string(16) "scottwills.co.uk"

Answer (score 2):

The code below should be perfect for the job.

```
function get_domain($url){
  $charge = explode('/', $url);
  $charge = $charge[2]; //assuming that the url starts with http:// or https://
  return $charge;
}

echo get_domain('http://www.example.com/example.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Simaple Code
You can get host, subdomain, domain, extension

```
$urls = array("https://www.face.com","www.asdasd.asd","sasdas.com/asdas","sdfsdf.sdf","https://app.abcdlink.com/user/test/");
```

Function :-

```
function getDomainname($a)
{
   $r = "(?P<host>(?:(?P<subdomain>[\w\.]+)\.)?" . "(?P<domain>\w+\.(?P<extension>\w+)))";
   $r = "!$r!";// Delimiters
   preg_match($r, $a, $out);

// if you need only domain then return $out['domain'];
// if you need only host then return $out['host'];
// if you need only subdomain then return $out['subdomain'];
// if you need only extension then return $out['extension'];

// Full Data array
    return $out;

}

$urls = array_map('getDomainname', $urls);
```

OR

```
function getsingaldomainHost($a)
{
    $a = (substr($a, 0, 7) == "http://" || substr($a, 0, 8) == "https://") ?  $a : 'http://' . $a;
    $r = "/(?P<host>(?:(?P<subdomain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{0,63}\.[a-z0-9]{0,62}))?(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{0,63}\.[a-z0-9]{0,62})(?P<extension>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{0,63}\.[a-z\.]{0,61}))$/i";
    $pieces = parse_url($a);
    if (isset($pieces['host'])) {
        $domain = substr($pieces['host'], 0, 4) == "www." ?  $pieces['host'] : 'www.' . $pieces['host'];
    } else {
        $domain = $pieces['path'];
    }

    if (preg_match($r, $domain, $regs)) {
        return substr($regs['host'], 0, 4) == "www." ? substr($regs['host'], 4) : $regs['host'];
    } else {
        if ($rr == 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $a;
        }
    }
}
$urls = array_map('getsingaldomainHost', $urls);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     if(substr_count($original_url, 'http://')) {
    if(substr_count($original_url, 'www.')) {
        // url style would be 'http://www.abc.xxx/page?param' or http://www.abc.xxx.xx/page?param
        // extract 'abc'
        $temp = explode('.', $original_url);

        $store_url = $temp[1];
        // now 
        // $temp[2] = xxx or xxx/page?param 
        // $temp[3] = null or xx/page?param 

        //if ($temp[3] == null) { // then we are sure that $temp[2]== "xxx/page?param"
                    if(sizeof($temp) > 3) {
            // extract "xxx" from "xxx/page?param" and append to store url so it will be "abc.xxx"  
            $temp = explode('/',$temp[2]);
            $store_url .= '.'.$temp[0];
        }
        else { 
            // then we are sure that $temp[2]== "xxx" and then $temp[3] == "xx/page?param"
            //                  or   $temp[2]== xxx/page?stripped-link from second dot(.)
            if(substr_count($temp[2], '/')) { // in case  $temp[2]== xxx/page?stripped-link from second dot(.)
                // extract "xxx" from "xxx/page?stripped-link" and appent to store url so it will be "abc.xxx"
                $temp = explode('/',$temp[2]);
                $store_url .= '.'.$temp[0]; // "abc".="xxx" ==> abc.xxx
            }
            else { // in case $temp[2]== "xxx" and then $temp[3] == "xx/page?param"
                $store_url .= '.'.$temp[2]; // "abc".="xxx" ==> abc.xxx
                // extract "xx" from "xx/page?param" and appent to store url so it will be "abc.xxx.xx"
                $temp = explode('/',$temp[3]);
                if(strlen($temp[0])==2) {
                    $store_url .= '.'.$temp[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // url style would be 'http://abc.xxx/page?param' or 'http://abc.xxx.xx/page?param'
        // remove 'http://'
        $temp = substr($original_url, 7);
        // now temp would be either 'abc.xxx/page?param' or 'abc.xxx.xx/page?param'
        // explode with '/'
        $temp = explode('/', $temp);
        $store_url = $temp[0];
    }
}
else if(substr_count($original_url, 'www.')) {
    // url style would be 'www.abc.xxx/page?param' or 'www.abc.xxx.xx/page?param'
    // remove 'www.'
    $temp = substr($original_url, 4);
    // now, $temp would be either "abc.xxx/page?param" or "abc.xxx.xx/page?param"
    // explode with '/'
    $temp = explode('/', $temp);
    $store_url = $temp[0];
}
else {
    // url style would be 'abc.xxx/page?param' or 'abc.xxx.xx/page?param'
    //explode with '/'
    $temp = explode('/', $original_url);
    $store_url = $temp[0];
}
```

Comment: it is function for getting host name from url.original url is your url and $store_url return host url..

Answer (score -5):

use this:

```
$uri = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";<br>
print($uri);
```

Example:

```
http://exemple.com/?directory<br>
Result:
/?diretory
```

The command get the directory and not domain.

Comment: The question relates to a URL a user has entered, not the address they are visiting.

Answer (score -5):

If you only want the domain name, try the following:

```
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

echo $domain;
```