# Get domain name without www and .com in PHP

Tags: php, regex, subdomain

I need to get domain name from URL excluding "www" and ".com" or ".co.uk" or anything other.

Example-

I have following urls like-

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.co.uk
http://subdomain.example.com
http://subdomain.example.co.uk
```

There will be anything at ".com" , ".org" , ".co.in", ".co.uk".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove domain extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3853338/53114)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try this it work for me.

```
    $original_url="http://subdomain.example.co.uk"; //try with all urls above

    $pieces = parse_url($original_url);
    $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
    if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain,    $regs)) {
       echo strstr( $regs['domain'], '.', true );
    }

Output- example
```

I get this from Here
[Get domain name from full URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027102/get-domain-name-from-full-url/16027164#16027164)

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*)\.(?=[\w.]{3,4})
```

Try this.See demo.Grab the capture.

http://regex101.com/r/bW3aR1/2

Answer (score 1):

You should use the PHP function [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) in combination with a `str_replace()` or regex, or maybe even an explode. It depends on a few things:

Things to note:

- Will there always be a subdomain?
- Will there be a specific list of allowed subdomains?

I would do something like this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.something.com';
$parts = explode('.', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
echo $parts[1]; // "something"
```

Comment: Which is why I added the Things to note: section, so I can get clarification on that.