# how to get only domain name from given URL in php

Tags: php

Suppose i have given URL, i want to get only domain name.
How do i achieve this in Php.

```
    +----------------------+------------+
    | input                | output     |
    +----------------------+------------+
    | www.google.com       | google     |
    | www.mail.yahoo.com   | mail.yahoo |
    | www.mail.yahoo.co.in | mail.yahoo |
    | www.abc.au.uk        | abc        |
     www.subdoamin.domain.co.in     // output subdomain
```

I applied the follwing trick but fails when i have TLD like "co.uk"

```
     if(isset($project_detail_all[0]->d_name)) {
        $domain_name = $project_detail_all[0]->d_name ;
        $domain_name = explode('.', $domain_name);
        $count = count($domain_name);
        if (top_level_domains($domain_name[$count-1]) && 
            stristr($rss_url, $domain_name[$count-2])) {
            return  isValidXML($rss_url);
        } else {
            return  ['status'=>false , 'invalid_Domain'=>true];
        }
    } else {
        return  ['status'=>false , 'invalid_Domain'=>true];
    }
```

Kindly help me

Comment: Look into this library function, this may help you very much! [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: <?php            $domain_name = 'http://www.abc.news18.co.in/abc.php' ;
            $ParsedURL = parse_url(strtolower($domain_name));
             
            if ($ParsedURL['host'] == null) {
                $domain_name = 'http://'.$domain_name;
                $ParsedURL = parse_url($domain_name);           
                $domain_name = explode('.', str_ireplace('www.', '', $ParsedURL['host']));
            } else {
                $domain_name = explode('.', str_ireplace('www.', '', $ParsedURL['host']));
            }
            print_r( $domain_name);

Comment: parse url will not work in this case

Comment: you need 'abc.news18' from the url, right?

Comment: no i want only new18

Comment: look this answer on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37987345/2679536), which can extract all parts of the url, from TLDExtract library.

Comment: ok, @PandhiBhaumik's answer is perfect for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `parse_url()`

```
<?php

    $url = parse_url("http://abc.news18.co.in");
    //echo $url['host'];
    echo preg_replace("/^([a-zA-Z0-9].*\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,})$/", '$2', $url['host']); 

?>
```

Comment: $domain_name = 'abc.news18.co.in/abc.php';

Comment: I added a regex which strips the subdomain.

Comment: its giving me news18.co.in , but i want only new18 and tld ('co.in') respectively

Comment: and again if url does not containing " http:// "  parse_url will not work

Comment: Then split the result: `$pieces = explode(" ", $url['host']); echo $pieces[1];`

Comment: And if it does not contain "http://", just add it: `$url = "abc.news18.co.in/page-to-article?whateverparameter=something";
 if (strpos($url, 'http://') == false)
   $url = "http://" . $url;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144658/discussion-between-kurt-van-den-branden-and-wasim-beg).

Comment: Thanks for solution , now i can tailor it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

please use regex to get only domain.

```
/.*?\.([A-z\d\.]+)(.co|.au)/s
```

You can see my solution result [here](https://regex101.com/r/6cqDaV/2). green colored text is result of regex.

Use below code.

```
$urls = ['www.google.com','www.mail.yahoo.com','www.mail.yahoo.co.in','www.abc.au.uk','www.subdoamin.domain.co.in','abc.news18.co.in/abc.php'];
$result = [];
foreach($urls as $url){
   preg_match('/.*?\.([A-z\d\.]+)(.co|.au)/s',$url,$match);
   $result[] = $match[1];
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

And you'll get result whatever you want.

Comment: It was not working before, now I've changed my answer and regex so it will work now, please open new updated link and you can get idea,