# get domain name from link with a fast and reliable method

Tags: php, url, dns, explode

Currently I am using this code to get the domain name (without www. or domain ending like .com):

```
explode('.', $url)[1];
```

Due to the fact that this code is in a loop it takes very long to handle it. Furthermore it can not get "example" from http://example.com/asd/asd.asd.html. Is there **another** and **faster** way to solve this?

Thank you for any answer in advance!

best greetings

Comment: http://php.net/parse_url

Comment: it can not isolate www. or domain endings ...

Comment: did you try the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027102/get-domain-name-from-full-url) question?

Comment: yes I did try it ... see my answer above pls

Comment: what should you get for www.bbc.co.uk/ or for http: // academia.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: bbc and stackexchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use parse_url()

```
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

PHP_URL_HOST returns the Host

Further, use a Regex to get the desired Part of the Host:

```
$result = preg_match('/^(?:www\.)?([^\.]+)/', $match);
```

Comment: thanks! but this does not handle the domain name problem

Comment: You're welcome! The Problem is: Subdomains versus Domains like .com.au. This is not easy to manage. You can have a Domain like: www.example.com or subdomain.example.com or example.com.au or subdomain.example.com.au. This is not manageable by that easy imho.

Comment: You need to use the public suffix list to accomplish this https://publicsuffix.org/