# Regular expression to replace a URL with just the domain name?

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I want to take in any URL as input, and output just the domain name, so no trailing slash after the .com or .co.uk etc) and also remove the www. and whatever comes before it (noting that there may not be a www.).

Examples:

http://google.com/dir1/dir2/index.php -> google.com
https://www.wonderfulworld.co.uk?a=1 -> wonderfulworld.co.uk

I will be using the `preg_replace` method in PHP.

Comment: post all the possible examples.

Comment: *"I will be using the `preg_replace` method in PHP."* - oh?

Comment: @AvinashRaj The URLs will be taken in as user input, so it could be anything that is a legal URL.

Comment: @Fred-ii- not sure how that's at all helpful?

Comment: What Regex have you tried?  If you're unsure how to write a regex in the first place maybe read up on them and use a site like http://rubular.com to test them.

Comment: Why are you saying "I" will be using... then? Show us what you've tried and where you think it's failing. As it stands, this is asking for code; *do* correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I should be fine with the start of the URL (http:// and www) but am unsure how to match the domain's suffix (.com or .co.uk). I do not know what the different variations are and what I should watch out for, for example not just matching . followed by 3 characters or . followed by 2 followed by . followed by 2 again etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing Domain From URL In PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of ***preg_replace*** you can use ***parse_url***

```
$url = 'http://google.com/dir1/dir2/index.php';
$parse = parse_url($url);
print $parse['host'];
```

**Output:**

google.com

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of that method. I'll need to tweak it slightly to remove www and www3 etc but apart from that it's perfect!