# Get Host name from given URL

Tags: php, url, html-parsing, url-parsing, urlparse

how to get host name from bellow Example.

> I/P: https://stackoverflow.com/users/login | O/P: stackoverflow.com
>
> I/P: stackoverflow.com/users/login | O/P: stackoverflow.com
>
> I/P: /users/login  | O/P: (return empty string)

I checked parse_url function, but doesn't return what I need. Since, I'm beginner in PHP, it was difficult for me. If you have any idea, please answer.

Comment: You need to create your own customised url parser.

Comment: ya thanks babak. I have tried my best. But didnt get proper output. Plz any one give me the proper function !

Comment: Have you tried: `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` or `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` but returns server name

Comment: It is not duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
<?php  

function getHost($Address) { 
   $parseUrl = parse_url(trim($Address)); 
   return trim(isset($parseUrl['host']) ? $parseUrl['host'] : array_shift(explode('/', $parseUrl['path'], 2))); 
} 

echo getHost('http://stackoverflow.com/users/login');
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work in all kind of domain name

```
$url = " https://stackoverflow.com/users/login";
// trailing slash for edge case, it will return empty string for strstr function regardless
$test = str_replace(array("http://", "https://"), "", $url) . "/";
$domain = strstr($test, "/", true);
echo $domain; // stackoverflow.com
```

`$domain` will be an empty string if no domain found

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
$url = ' https://stackoverflow.com/users/login';

function return_host($url)
{
  $url = str_replace(array('http://', 'https://'), '', $url); // remove protocol if present
  $temp = explode('/', $url); // explode the url by /
  if(strpos($temp[0], '.com')) { // check the url part
     return $temp[0];
  }
  else {
     return false;
  }
}

echo return_host($url);
```

**Update**

For other domain types just change the check -

```
if(strpos($temp[0], '.com') || strpos($temp[0], '.org') || strpos($temp[0], '.net'))
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/469302)

Comment: @SanKaRan For that you just have to change the check.

Comment: ya. Now it's k. million  tanks @karan

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, as described in this solution: [Getting parts of a URL (Regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745/getting-parts-of-a-url-regex)

Or you can use a PHP function for that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

I would suggest the second (RegExes can be tricky if you don't know exactly how they work).

Comment: I have tried parse-url. but from this inbuilt function, I didnt get proper output.

Comment: can you paste your code? I know it works, so there may be something wrong in there...