# how can I remove folder name from url in php?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have created index.php file and give header i.e

```
<?php

header('location:/cicareer/members');

?>
```

url is:

```
careermate.in/cicareer/members
```

I want to remove

```
/cicareer/members
```

So, how could I do this using `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: You can use explode command --> $url = "careermate.in/cicareer/members"; $pieces = explode("/", $url);
echo $pieces[0];  --> that should echo careermate.in

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php

Answer (score 0):

This line may help in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /cicareer/members/index.php
```

In order to use this you need to have mod_rewrite module enabled in your httpd.conf