# Exact an IP address out of a Host URL

Tags: php, substring, ip-address, host

I have a host = `http://172.19.242.32:1234/`

My goal is to grab the IP only = `172.19.242.32`

I tried

```
$ip = trim($host,'http://');
$ip = str_replace("/", "",$ip);
$ip = explode(":",$ip);
$ip = $ip[0];
```

I got my IP as expected, but I can't do it this way anymore because it will mess up the IPv6 format.

What is the alternative way? Any suggestion?

Comment: [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: Or the regex `/[\d.]+(?=:)/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing Domain From URL In PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php): You can ommit `PHP_URL_HOST` to return an array of all components.

```
<?php
$host = 'http://172.19.242.32:1234/';
echo parse_url($host, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

returns

```
172.19.242.32
```

https://eval.in/770497

Comment: It returns ``[fd8c::11]``.

Comment: Awesome, then it is the right answer. I will accept it soon.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url="http://172.19.242.32:1234/";
$regexIpAddress = '/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:\/\d{2})?/';        
preg_match_all($regexIpAddress, $url, $ip_match);
var_dump($ip_match[0]);
```

This reg expression match function will extract ip address from any string.

Comment: Too complicated,  
Will this work with IPv6 ?? Ex. host=http://[fd8c::11]:1234/ ?

Comment: This is IPv4 regex match.

Answer (score -2):

The right way would be `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` I think? It should return just the IP

Comment: This will return the IP address of the server under which the current script is executing. OP asked to get IP address from a certain string.

Comment: He said he had a host, I interpreted that as his own host, where the script is run.