# Get base url from string

Tags: php

I have a simple script like this

```
$data = "http://example.com/index.php?data=data&value=value";
```

How to get base url from $data? The output will be like this

```
http://example.com
```

The output without this text " /index.php?data=data&value=value

Comment: use  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

Comment: If i use thats code, the output will be localhost url, but, i want the url from $data

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use **parse_url()**

```
$url = "http://example.com/index.php?data=data&value=value";
$url_info = parse_url($url);
echo $url_info['host'];//hostname
```

Additionally **$user_info** contain below

```
[scheme] => http
[host] => hostname
[user] => username
[pass] => password
[path] => /path
[query] => arg=value
[fragment] => anchor
```

SO you can get **http** by scheme

you can do something like :

`echo  $url_info['scheme'] . '://' . $url_info['host'];`//http://example.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) included scheme and hostname.

```
$url = "http://example.com/index.php?data=data&value=value";
$base_url = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
echo $base_url;
```

Output:

```
http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [Parsing Domain From URL In PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-url-in-php?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
$url = 'http://google.com/dhasjkdas/sadsdds/sdda/sdads.html';
$parse = parse_url($url);
echo $parse['host']; // prints 'google.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url= parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Why can't we just use this. Worked for me.