# php string replace http to https (with www or not)

Tags: php

I've a string like this:

```
$url = '<p>IMAGE 1:</p><img src="http://example.com/image1.jpg"><br><p>IMAGE 2:</p><img src="http://www.example.com/image2.jpg"><br><p>IMAGE 3:</p><img src="http://externalsite.com/image3.jpg"><br><p>IMAGE 4:</p><img src="http://www.externalsite.com/image4.jpg">'
```

example.com is the domain where my webapp is located.

I need:

1. check if example.com is http or https
2. if https, replace all http://example.com and http://www.example.com in my string to: https://www.example.com (so not include other domains like externalsite.com)

For first point I can use: `$isHttps = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? true : false;`

For second point i'm not sure how create a preg_replace correctly

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50653452/6309457

Comment: The domain `mysite.com` does not appear anywhere in your input string.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen corrected: example.com

Comment: @DevsiOdedra my string has different urls inside...and others text,span,div etc... it is not only a single url

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the logic you want.  We can search for the following regex pattern:

```
http://(?:www\.)?example\.com
```

This would match both `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com`.  Then, we can replace with the `https` version of these URLs.

```
$url = '<p>IMAGE 1:</p><img src="http://example.com/image1.jpg"><br><p>IMAGE 2:</p><img src="http://www.example.com/image2.jpg"><br><p>IMAGE 3:</p><img src="http://externalsite.com/image3.jpg"><br><p>IMAGE 4:</p><img src="http://www.externalsite.com/image4.jpg">';
$output = preg_replace("/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?example\.com/", "https://www.example.com", $url);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
<p>IMAGE 1:</p><img src="https://www.example.com/image1.jpg"><br><p>IMAGE 2:</p><img src="https://www.example.com/image2.jpg"><br><p>IMAGE 3:</p><img src="http://externalsite.com/image3.jpg"><br><p>IMAGE 4:</p><img src="http://www.externalsite.com/image4.jpg">
```

Comment: I'mm try thanks...but...how can I manipulate example.com as a $variable inside preg_replace? i don't want to hardcode example.com

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini You must at least know which _variables_ contain the URLs you want to target/replace.  Just use `preg_quote()` on them, and then do the replacement on that.

Comment: variables is $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']