# How to get a domain variable value

Tags: javascript, html

so I have a question, which maybe it's a little ez, but... I don't know hehe, so, how do you get a value that's in the domain? like:

```
https://example.com?test=helloworld
```

how do I get the value of the "test" variable that is there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing domain from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276516/parsing-domain-from-a-url)

Comment: Do you mean `https://example.com/?test=helloworld`. Or is the missing `?` deliberate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean `https://example.com?test=helloworld` including a `?`.

**Reading Value from URL**

```js
const url = new URL('https://example.com?test=helloworld');

console.log(url.searchParams.get("test")); // prints: helloworld
```

And to get the current URL you can use `window.location.href`.

---

**Add Value to URL**

```js
const url = new URL('https://example.com');

url.searchParams.append('test', 'helloworld');

console.log(url.href);  // prints: https://example.com?test=helloworld
```

---

Have a look at the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API) on the MDN documentation.